# How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in GCC?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, gcc, disassembly

How does one do this?

If I want to analyze how something is getting compiled, how would I get the emitted assembly code?

Comment: For tips on **making the asm output human readable**, see also: [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

Answer (score 593, accepted):

Use the [-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) option to `gcc` (or `g++`), optionally with [-fverbose-asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fverbose-asm) which works well at the default [-O0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O0) to attach C names to asm operands as comments. It works less well at any optimization level, which you normally want to use to get asm worth looking at.

```
gcc -S helloworld.c
```

This will run the preprocessor (cpp) over *helloworld.c*, perform the initial compilation and then stop before the assembler is run.  For useful compiler options to use in that case, see *[How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)* (or just **look at your code on [Matt Godbolt's online Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)** which filters out directives and stuff, and has highlighting to match up source lines with asm using debug information.)

By default, this will output the file `helloworld.s`. The output file can be still be set by using the [-o](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-o) option, including `-o -` to write to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) for pipe into [less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)).

```
gcc -S -o my_asm_output.s helloworld.c
```

Of course, this only works if you have the original source.
An alternative if you only have the resultant object file is to use [objdump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump), by setting the `--disassemble` option (or `-d` for the abbreviated form).

```
objdump -S --disassemble helloworld > helloworld.dump
```

`-S` interleaves source lines with normal disassembly output, so this option works best if debugging option is enabled for the object file ([-g](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g) at compilation time) and the file hasn't been stripped.

Running `file helloworld` will give you some indication as to the level of detail that you will get by using *objdump*.

Other useful `objdump` options include `-rwC` (to show symbol relocations, disable line-wrapping of long machine code, and demangle C++ names). And if you don't like AT&T syntax for x86, `-Mintel`.  See [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html).

So for example, `objdump -drwC -Mintel -S foo.o | less`.
`-r` is very important with a `.o` that only has `00 00 00 00` placeholders for symbol references, as opposed to a linked executable.

Comment: an addition use : objdump -M intel -S --disassemble helloworld > helloworld.dump to get the object dump in intel syntax compatible with nasm on linux.

Comment: If you have a single function to optimize/check, then you can give a try to online Interactive C++ Compilers i.e. [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Comment: @touchStone: **GAS `.intel_syntax` is *not* compatible with NASM**.  It's more like MASM (e.g. `mov eax, symbol` is a load, unlike in NASM where it's a `mov r32, imm32` of the address), but not totally compatible with MASM either.  I do highly recommend it as a nice format to read, especially if you like to write in NASM syntax though. `objdump -drwC -Mintel | less` or `gcc foo.c -O1 -fverbose-asm -masm=intel -S -o- | less` are useful.  (See also [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116)).  `-masm=intel` works with clang, too.

Comment: Better use `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S`

Comment: Why `objdump -S` has no noise whereas `gcc -S` has noise output ?

Answer (score 211):

This will generate assembly code with the C code + line numbers interwoven, to more easily see which lines generate what code ([-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) [-fverbose-asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fverbose-asm) [-g](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g) [-O2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O2)):

```bash
# Create assembler code:
g++ -S -fverbose-asm -g -O2 test.cc -o test.s

# Create asm interlaced with source lines:
as -alhnd test.s > test.lst
```

It was found in [Algorithms for programmers](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtbook.pdf), page 3 (which is the overall 15th page of the PDF).

Comment: Sadly, `as` on OS X doesn't know these flags. If it did, though, you could probably one-line this using `-Wa` to pass options to `as`.

Comment: `g++ -g -O0 -c -fverbose-asm -Wa,-adhln test.cpp > test.lst` would be the short hand version of this.

Comment: You can also use either `gcc -c -g -Wa,-ahl=test.s test.c` or `gcc -c -g -Wa,-a,-ad test.c > test.txt`

Comment: A [blog post](http://www.systutorials.com/240/generate-a-mixed-source-and-assembly-listing-using-gcc/) explaining this in more detail, including the one-command version like legends and Lu'u posted.  But why `-O0`?  That's full of loads/stores that make it hard to track a value, and doesn't tell you anything about how efficient the optimized code will be.

Answer (score 54):

The following command line is from [Christian Garbin's blog](http://christiangarbin.blogspot.com/2013/05/c-generating-assembly-code-with-gccg.html):

```
g++ -g -O -Wa,-aslh horton_ex2_05.cpp >list.txt
```

I ran G++ from a DOS window on Windows XP, against a routine that contains an implicit cast

```
cd C:\gpp_code
g++ -g -O -Wa,-aslh horton_ex2_05.cpp > list.txt
```

Output:

```
horton_ex2_05.cpp: In function `int main()':
horton_ex2_05.cpp:92: warning: assignment to `int' from `double'
```

The output is assembled generated code, interspersed with the original C++ code (the C++ code is shown as comments in the generated assembly language stream)

```
  16:horton_ex2_05.cpp **** using std::setw;
  17:horton_ex2_05.cpp ****
  18:horton_ex2_05.cpp **** void disp_Time_Line (void);
  19:horton_ex2_05.cpp ****
  20:horton_ex2_05.cpp **** int main(void)
  21:horton_ex2_05.cpp **** {
 164                    %ebp
 165                            subl $128,%esp
?GAS LISTING C:\DOCUME~1\CRAIGM~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccx52rCc.s
166 0128 55                    call ___main
167 0129 89E5          .stabn 68,0,21,LM2-_main
168 012b 81EC8000      LM2:
168      0000
169 0131 E8000000      LBB2:
169      00
170                    .stabn 68,0,25,LM3-_main
171                    LM3:
172                            movl $0,-16(%ebp)
```

Comment: @Paladin - Not necessarily. The OP was about getting the assembler output equivalent of the C/C++ source code, this gets the Listing, which I agree is more useful for understanding what the compiler and optimizer is doing. But it would cause the assembler itself to barf, as it is not expecting the line numbers, and compiled bytes off tot he left of the assembly instructions.

Comment: Use at least `-O2`, or whatever optimization options you actually use when building your project, if you want to see how gcc optimizes your code.  (Or if you use LTO, like you should, then you have to disassemble the linker output to see what you really get.)

Comment: @PeterCordes there is an easier way, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635734/getting-assember-output-from-gcc-clang-in-lto-mode)

Answer (score 38):

Use the [-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) switch:

```
g++ -S main.cpp
```

Or also with `gcc`:

```
gcc -S main.c
```

Also see [this](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html).

Answer (score 34):

**`-save-temps`**

This was mentioned in [METADATA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc/17083009#17083009), but let me further exemplify it.

The big advantage of this option over [-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) is that it is very easy to add it to any build script, without interfering much in the build itself:

```
gcc -save-temps -c -o main.o main.c
```

main.c

```
#define INC 1

int myfunc(int i) {
    return i + INC;
}
```

and now, besides the normal output `main.o`, the current working directory also contains the following files:

- `main.i` is a bonus and contains the preprocessed file:

  ```
  # 1 "main.c"
  # 1 "<built-in>"
  # 1 "<command-line>"
  # 31 "<command-line>"
  # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
  # 32 "<command-line>" 2
  # 1 "main.c"


  int myfunc(int i) {
      return i + 1;
  }
  ```
- `main.s` contains the desired generated assembly:

  ```
      .file    "main.c"
      .text
      .globl    myfunc
      .type    myfunc, @function
  myfunc:
  .LFB0:
      .cfi_startproc
      pushq    %rbp
      .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
      .cfi_offset 6, -16
      movq    %rsp, %rbp
      .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
      movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
      movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
      addl    $1, %eax
      popq    %rbp
      .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
      ret
      .cfi_endproc
  .LFE0:
      .size    myfunc, .-myfunc
      .ident    "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0"
      .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
  ```

Docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-save-temps

**`-save-temps=obj`**

If you want to do it for a large number of files, consider using instead:

```
-save-temps=obj
```

which saves the intermediate files to the same directory as the `-o` object output instead of the current working directory, thus avoiding potential basename conflicts.

For example:

```
gcc -save-temps -c -o out/subdir/main.o subdir/main.c
```

leads to the creation of files:

```
out/subdir/main.i
out/subdir/main.o
out/subdir/main.s
```

Clearly an Apple plot to take over the world.

**`-save-temps -v`**

Another cool thing about this option is if you add `-v`:

```
gcc -save-temps -c -o main.o -v main.c
```

it actually shows the explicit files being used instead of ugly temporaries under `/tmp`, so it is easy to know exactly what is going on, which includes the preprocessing / compilation / assembly steps:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu main.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fpch-preprocess -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o main.i
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1 -fpreprocessed main.i -quiet -dumpbase main.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip main.o -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o main.s
as -v --64 -o main.o main.s
```

It was tested in [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.04_(Disco_Dingo)) (Disco Dingo) amd64, GCC 8.3.0.

**CMake predefined targets**

CMake automatically provides a targets for the preprocessed file:

```
make help
```

shows us that we can do:

```
make main.s
```

and that target runs:

```
Compiling C source to assembly CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.s
/usr/bin/cc    -S /home/ciro/hello/main.c -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.s
```

so the file can be seen at `CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.s`.

It was tested on CMake 3.16.1.

Answer (score 15):

If what you want to see depends on the linking of the output, then [objdump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) on the output object file/executable may also be useful in addition to [the aforementioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc/137044#137044) `gcc -S`.  Here's a very useful script by Loren Merritt that converts the default objdump syntax into the more readable [NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$ptr='(BYTE|WORD|DWORD|QWORD|XMMWORD) PTR ';
$reg='(?:[er]?(?:[abcd]x|[sd]i|[sb]p)|[abcd][hl]|r1?[0-589][dwb]?|mm[0-7]|xmm1?[0-9])';
open FH, '-|', '/usr/bin/objdump', '-w', '-M', 'intel', @ARGV or die;
$prev = "";
while(<FH>){
    if(/$ptr/o) {
        s/$ptr(\[[^\[\]]+\],$reg)/$2/o or
        s/($reg,)$ptr(\[[^\[\]]+\])/$1$3/o or
        s/$ptr/lc $1/oe;
    }
    if($prev =~ /\t(repz )?ret / and
       $_ =~ /\tnop |\txchg *ax,ax$/) {
       # drop this line
    } else {
       print $prev;
       $prev = $_;
    }
}
print $prev;
close FH;
```

I suspect this can also be used on the output of `gcc -S`.

Comment: Still, this script is a dirty hack which doesn't fully convert the syntax. E.g. `mov    eax,ds:0x804b794` is not very NASMish. Also, sometimes it just strips useful information: `movzx  eax,[edx+0x1]` leaves the reader to guess whether the memory operand was `byte` or `word`.

Comment: To disassemble in NASM syntax in the first place, use [Agner Fog's `objconv`](http://agner.org/optimize/#objconv).  You can get it to disassemble to stdout with output file = `/dev/stdout`, so you can pipe into `less` for viewing.  There's also `ndisasm`, but it only disassembles flat binaries, and doesn't know about object files (ELF / PE).

Answer (score 13):

Well, as everyone said, use the [-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) option.

If you use the [-save-temps](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-save-temps) option, you can also get the preprocessed file (*.i), assembly file (*.s) and object file (*.o) (get each of them by using [-E](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-E), [-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S), and [-c](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c), respectively).

Answer (score 10):

As everyone has pointed out, use the [`-S`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) option to GCC.  I would also like to add that the results may vary (wildly!) depending on whether or not you add optimization options ([`-O0`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O0) for none, [`-O2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O2) for aggressive optimization).

On RISC architectures in particular, the compiler will often transform the code almost beyond recognition in doing optimization.  It's impressive and fascinating to look at the results!

Answer (score 9):

Use the [-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) option:

```
gcc -S program.c
```

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned before, look at the [-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) flag.

It's also worth looking at the '-fdump-tree' family of flags, in particular [-fdump-tree-all](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-fdump-tree-all), which lets you see some of GCC's intermediate forms. These can often be more readable than assembler (at least to me), and let you see how optimisation passes perform.

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for LLVM assembly:

```
llvm-gcc -emit-llvm -S hello.c
```

Comment: The question was about GCC, not [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM).

Answer (score 9):

I don't see this possibility among answers, probably because the question is from 2008, but in 2018 you can use Matt Goldbolt's online website https://godbolt.org

You can also locally git clone and run his project https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer

Comment: [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc/137074#137074) has been updated with that information.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution for C using GCC:

```
gcc -S program.c && gcc program.c -o output
```

1. Here the first part stores the assembly output of the program in the same file name as the *program*, but with a changed **.s** extension, you can open it as any normal text file.
2. The second part here compiles your program for actual usage and generates an executable for your Program with a specified file name.

The *program.c* used above is the name of your program and *output* is the name of the executable you want to generate.

Comment: You can also use `gcc -O2 -save-temps foo.c` to compile+assemble+link, but save the intermediate `.s` and `.o` files, instead of separately running a build that only compiles to asm.  (But also a `.i` preprocessed C file).  So it's fewer steps, but produces files you don't want.

Answer (score 6):

From the FAQ *[How to get GCC to generate assembly code](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html)*:

*gcc [-c](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c) [-g](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g) [-Wa,-a,-ad](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Assembler-Options.html#index-Wa) [other GCC options] foo.c > foo.lst*

as an alternative to [PhirePhly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc/137479#137479).

Or just use [-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) as everyone said.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Output of these commands]

Here are the steps to see/print the assembly code of any C program on your Windows:

In a console/terminal command prompt:

1. Write a C program in a C code editor like [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) and save it with filename extension .c
2. Compile and run it.
3. Once run successfully, go to the folder where you have installed your GCC compiler and enter the following command to get a ' .s ' file of the ' .c' file

   ```
   cd C:\gcc
   gcc -S complete path of the C file  ENTER
   ```

   An example command (as in my case)

   ```
   gcc  -S D:\Aa_C_Certified\alternate_letters.c
   ```

   This outputs a '.s' file of the original '.c' file.
4. After this, type the following command

   ```
   cpp filename.s ENTER
   ```

   Example command (as in my case)

   ```
   cpp alternate_letters.s  <enter>
   ```

This will print/output the entire assembly language code of your C program.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I wanted to know the assembly of each functions in a. This is how I did it:

```
gcc main.c    // 'main.c' source file
gdb a.exe     // 'gdb a.out' in Linux
```

In GDB:

```
disass main   // Note here 'main' is a function
              // Similarly, it can be done for other functions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "-S" as an option. It displays the assembly output in the terminal.

Comment: To display in the terminal, use `gcc foo.c -masm=intel -fverbose-asm -O3 -S -o- |less`.  `-S` on its own creates `foo.s`.

Comment: This is already covered by previous answers.