# Using GCC to produce readable assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I was wondering how to use [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) on my C source file to dump a mnemonic version of the machine code so I could see what my code was being compiled into. You can do this with Java but I haven't been able to find a way with GCC.

I am trying to re-write a C method in assembly and seeing how GCC does it would be a big help.

Comment: note that 'bytecode' typically means the code consumed by a VM, like JVM or .NET's CLR.  The output of GCC is better called 'machine code', 'machine language', or 'assembly language'

Comment: I added an answer using godbolt since it is a very powerful tool for rapidly experimenting with how different options effect your code generation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19083877/995714

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc)

Comment: For more tips on making the asm output human readable, see also: [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38552509/224132)

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc Use the -S option to gcc (or g++).

Answer (score 398, accepted):

If you compile with debug symbols (add `-g` to your GCC command line, even if you're also using `-O3`<sup>1</sup>),
you can use `objdump -S` to produce a more readable disassembly interleaved with C source.

```
>objdump --help
[...]
-S, --source             Intermix source code with disassembly
-l, --line-numbers       Include line numbers and filenames in output
```

`objdump -drwC -Mintel` is nice:

- `-r` shows symbol names on relocations (so you'd see `puts` in the `call` instruction below)
- `-R` shows dynamic-linking relocations / symbol names (useful on shared libraries)
- `-C` demangles C++ symbol names
- `-w` is "wide" mode: it doesn't line-wrap the machine-code bytes
- `-Mintel`: use GAS/binutils MASM-like `.intel_syntax noprefix` syntax instead of AT&T
- `-S`: interleave source lines with disassembly.

You could put something like `alias disas="objdump -drwCS -Mintel"` in your `~/.bashrc`.  If not on x86, or if you like AT&T syntax, omit `-Mintel`.

---

Example:

```
> gcc -g -c test.c
> objdump -d -M intel -S test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
    puts("test");
   9:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x0
  10:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   11 <main+0x11>

    return 0;
  15:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
}
  1a:   c9                      leave  
  1b:   c3                      ret
```

Note that this *isn't* using `-r` so the `call rel32=-4` isn't annotated with the `puts` symbol name.  And looks like a broken `call` that jumps into the middle of the call instruction in main.  Remember that the `rel32` displacement in the call encoding is just a placeholder until the linker fills in a real offset (to a PLT stub in this case, unless you statically link libc).

---

**Footnote 1**:  Interleaving source can be messy and not very helpful in optimized builds; for that, consider https://godbolt.org/ or other ways of visualizing which instructions go with which source lines.  In optimized code there's [not always a single source line that accounts for an instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794280/how-to-use-objdump-to-interleave-source-code-in-highly-optimized-object-file) but the debug info will pick one source line for each asm instruction.

Comment: Is there a switch to grab only the Intel instructions?

Comment: All of these are Intel instructions since they run on Intel processors :D.

Comment: @toto I think he means Intel syntax instead of AT&T syntax

Comment: It is possible to forgo the intermediate object file with the by using the switch sequence `-Wa,-adhln -g to gcc`. This assumes that the assembler is gas and this may not always be the case.

Comment: @James Yes, supply `-Mintel`.

Comment: Use `otool -tV` for Mac user :)

Answer (score 129):

If you give [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) the flag `-fverbose-asm`, it will

> Put extra commentary information in the generated assembly code to make it more readable.
>
> [...] The added comments include:
>
> - information on the compiler version and command-line options,
> - the source code lines associated with the assembly instructions, in the form FILENAME:LINENUMBER:CONTENT OF LINE,
> - hints on which high-level expressions correspond to the various assembly instruction operands.

Comment: But then, I would lost all the switch used for `objdump` - `objdump -drwCS -Mintel`, so how can I use something like `verbose` with `objdump`? So that I can have comments in asm code, as does `-fverbose-asm` in gcc?

Comment: @Herdsman: you can't. The extra stuff `-fverbose-asm` adds is in the form of comments in the asm syntax of the output, not directives that will put anything extra in the `.o` file.  It's all discarded at assemble time.  Look at compiler asm output *instead* of disassembly, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ where you can easily match it up with the source line via mouseover and color highlighting of corresponding source / asm lines.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Answer (score 82):

> Use the -S (note: capital S) switch to GCC, and it will emit the assembly code to a file with a .s extension. For example, the following command:
>
> `gcc -O2 -S foo.c`
>
> will leave the generated assembly code on the file foo.s.

Ripped straight from http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html (but removing erroneous `-c`)

Comment: You shouldn't mix -c and -S, only use one of them.  In this case, one is overriding the other, probably depending on the order in which they're used.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Any reference about 'shouldn't mix -c and -S'? If it is true, we may should remind the author and edit it.

Comment: @Tony: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options "You can use ... ***one*** of the options -c, -S, or -E to say where gcc is to stop."

Comment: If you want all the intermediate outputs, use `gcc -march=native -O3 -save-temps`.  You can still use `-c` to stop at object-file creation without trying to link, or whatever.

Comment: `-save-temps` is interesting as it dumps in one go the exact code generated code, whereas the other option of calling the compiler with `-S` means compiling twice, and possibly with different options. **But** `-save-temps` dumps all in the current directory, which is kind of messy. Looks like it is more intended as a debug option for GCC rather than a tool to inspect your code.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon: That's correct; more for debugging / creating compiler bug reports than for this use-case.  I never use `-save-temps` for looking at how some source compiled to asm, either `-masm=intel -S -o- | less`, disassemble the `.o` or executable, or put it on https://godbolt.org/.

Comment: Use `-save-temps=obj` to have gcc write the generated `.i` and `.s` files to the same directory to where it writes the `.o` object file.

Answer (score 55):

Using the `-S` switch to GCC on x86 based systems produces a dump of AT&T syntax, by default, which can be specified with the `-masm=att` switch, like so:

```sh
gcc -S -masm=att code.c
```

Whereas if you'd like to produce a dump in Intel syntax, you could use the `-masm=intel` switch, like so:

```sh
gcc -S -masm=intel code.c
```

(Both produce dumps of `code.c` into their various syntax, into the file `code.s` respectively)

In order to produce similar effects with objdump, you'd want to use the `--disassembler-options=` `intel`/`att` switch, an example (with code dumps to illustrate the differences in syntax):

```sh
 $ objdump -d --disassembler-options=att code.c
```

```
 080483c4 <main>:
 80483c4:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 80483c8:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80483cb:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 80483ce:   55                      push   %ebp
 80483cf:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483d1:   51                      push   %ecx
 80483d2:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 80483d5:   c7 04 24 b0 84 04 08    movl   $0x80484b0,(%esp)
 80483dc:   e8 13 ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <puts@plt>
 80483e1:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 80483e6:   83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp 
 80483e9:   59                      pop    %ecx
 80483ea:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 80483eb:   8d 61 fc                lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
 80483ee:   c3                      ret
 80483ef:   90                      nop
```

and

```sh
$ objdump -d --disassembler-options=intel code.c
```

```
 080483c4 <main>:
 80483c4:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
 80483c8:   83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
 80483cb:   ff 71 fc                push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
 80483ce:   55                      push   ebp
 80483cf:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 80483d1:   51                      push   ecx
 80483d2:   83 ec 04                sub    esp,0x4
 80483d5:   c7 04 24 b0 84 04 08    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x80484b0
 80483dc:   e8 13 ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <puts@plt>
 80483e1:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
 80483e6:   83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
 80483e9:   59                      pop    ecx
 80483ea:   5d                      pop    ebp
 80483eb:   8d 61 fc                lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
 80483ee:   c3                      ret    
 80483ef:   90                      nop
```

Comment: What the... `gcc -S -masm=intel test.c` didn't exactly work for me, I got some crossbreed of Intel and AT&T syntax like this: `mov %rax, QWORD PTR -24[%rbp]`, instead of this: `movq -24(%rbp), %rax`.

Comment: Nice tip. It should be noted this also works when performing parallel output of `.o` and ASM files, i.e. via `-Wa,-ahls -o yourfile.o yourfile.cpp>yourfile.asm`

Comment: Could use `-M` option, it's the same as `--disassembler-options` but much shorter, e.g `objdump -d -M intel a.out | less -N`

Answer (score 35):

[godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#) is a very useful tool, they list only has C++ compilers but you can use `-x c` flag in order to get it treat the code as C. It will then generate an assembly listing for your code side by side and you can use the `Colourise` option to generate colored bars to visually indicate which source code maps to the generated assembly. For example the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func()
{
  printf( "hello world\n" ) ;
}
```

using the following command line:

```
-x c -std=c99 -O3
```

and `Colourise` would generate the following:

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to know how godbolt filters work: .LC0, .text, //, and Intel.  Intel is easy `-masm=intel` but what about the rest?

Comment: I guess it is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38552509/2542702

Comment: godbolt do support C (along with a ton of other languages like Rust, D, Pascal...). It's just that there are much fewer C compilers, so it's still better to use C++ compilers with `-x c`

Comment: Why are the strings different between the source and the assembly? The newline has been stripped at the end

Answer (score 27):

Did you try `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O source.c` then look into the generated `source.s` assembler file ?

The generated assembler code goes into `source.s` (you could override that with `-o` *assembler-filename* ); the `-fverbose-asm` option asks the compiler to emit some assembler comments "explaining" the generated assembler code. The `-O` option asks the compiler to optimize a bit (it could optimize more with `-O2` or `-O3`).

If you want to understand what `gcc` is doing try passing `-fdump-tree-all` but be cautious: you'll get hundreds of dump files.

BTW, GCC is extensible thru [plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) or with [MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) (a high level domain specific language to extend GCC; which I abandoned in 2017)

Comment: maybe mention that the output will be in `source.s`, since a lot of people would expect a printout on the console.

Comment: @ecerulm: `-S -o-` dumps to stdout.  `-masm=intel` is helpful if you want to use NASM/YASM syntax.  (but it uses `qword ptr [mem]`, rather than just `qword`, so it's more like Intel/MASM than NASM/YASM).  http://gcc.godbolt.org/ does a nice job of tidying up the dump: optionally stripping comment-only lines, unused labels, and assembler directives.

Comment: Forgot to mention: If you're looking for "similar to the source but without the noise of store/reload after every source line", then `-Og` is even better than `-O1`.  It means "optimize for debugging" and makes asm without too many tricky / hard-to-follow optimizations that does everything the source says.  It's been available since gcc4.8, but clang 3.7 still doesn't have it.  IDK if they decided against it or what.

Comment: Update: clang supports `-Og` now.  Also, see [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) for more about writing test functions that compile to interesting asm to look at, and GCC/clang options for looking at their asm output directly, not disassembly.  IDK why the answers to this question are mostly about disassembly, not GCC asm output.

Answer (score 17):

You can use gdb for this like objdump.

This excerpt is taken from http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_9.html#SEC64

---

Here is an example showing mixed source+assembly for Intel x86:

```
  (gdb) disas /m main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
5       {
0x08048330 :    push   %ebp
0x08048331 :    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048333 :    sub    $0x8,%esp
0x08048336 :    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x08048339 :    sub    $0x10,%esp

6         printf ("Hello.\n");
0x0804833c :   movl   $0x8048440,(%esp)
0x08048343 :   call   0x8048284 

7         return 0;
8       }
0x08048348 :   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0804834d :   leave
0x0804834e :   ret

End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: archieved link: https://web.archive.org/web/20090412112833/http://sourceware.org:80/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_9.html

Comment: And to switch GDB's disassembler to Intel syntax, use `set disassembly-flavor intel` command.

Answer (score 13):

Use the -S (note: capital S) switch to GCC, and it will emit the assembly code to a file with a .s extension. For example, the following command:

gcc -O2 -S -c foo.c

Answer (score 6):

I haven't given a shot to `gcc`, but in case of `g++`, the command below works for me.

- `-g` for debug build
- `-Wa,-adhln` are passed to assembler for listing with source code

```sh
g++ -g -Wa,-adhln src.cpp
```

Comment: It works for gcc too! -Wa,... is for command line options for the assembler part (execute in gcc/g++ after C/++ compilation). It invokes as internally (as.exe in Windows).
See 

 >as --help 

as command line to see more help

Answer (score 2):

For risc-v dissasembly, these flags are nice:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d -S -l --visualize-jumps --disassembler-color=color --inlines
```

`-d`: disassemble, most basic flag

`-S`: intermix source. Note: must use `-g` flag while compiling

`-l`: line numbers

`--visualize-jumps`: fancy arrows, not too useful but why not. Sometimes get's too messy and actually makes reading the source harder. Taken from `Peter Cordes`'s comment: `--visualize-jumps=color`is also an option, to use different colors for different arrows

`--disassembler-color=color`: give the disassembly some color

`--inlines`: print out inlines

Maybe usefull:

`-M numeric`: Use numeric reg names instead of abi names, useful if you are doing cpu dev and don't know the abi names by heart

`-M no-aliases`: don't use psudoinstructions like `li` and `call`

Example:
`main.o`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static inline void example_inline(const char* str) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
        putchar(str[i]);
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello world");
    example_inline("Hello! I am inlined");

    return 0;
}
```

I recommend to use `-O0` if you want intermix sources. Intermix sources becomes very messy if using `-O2`.

Command:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc main.c -c -O0 -g
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d -S -l --disassembler-color=color --inlines main.o
```

Dissasembly:

```
main.o:     file format elf64-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <example_inline>:
example_inline():
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:4
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static inline void example_inline(const char* str) {
   0:   7179                    addi    sp,sp,-48
   2:   f406                    sd  ra,40(sp)
   4:   f022                    sd  s0,32(sp)
   6:   1800                    addi    s0,sp,48
   8:   fca43c23                sd  a0,-40(s0)

000000000000000c <.LBB2>:
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:5
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
   c:   fe042623                sw  zero,-20(s0)
  10:   a01d                    j   36 <.L2>

0000000000000012 <.L3>:
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:6 (discriminator 3)
        putchar(str[i]);
  12:   fec42783                lw  a5,-20(s0)
  16:   fd843703                ld  a4,-40(s0)
  1a:   97ba                    add a5,a5,a4
  1c:   0007c783                lbu a5,0(a5)
  20:   2781                    sext.w  a5,a5
  22:   853e                    mv  a0,a5
  24:   00000097                auipc   ra,0x0
  28:   000080e7                jalr    ra # 24 <.L3+0x12>
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:5 (discriminator 3)
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
  2c:   fec42783                lw  a5,-20(s0)
  30:   2785                    addiw   a5,a5,1
  32:   fef42623                sw  a5,-20(s0)

0000000000000036 <.L2>:
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:5 (discriminator 1)
  36:   fec42783                lw  a5,-20(s0)
  3a:   fd843703                ld  a4,-40(s0)
  3e:   97ba                    add a5,a5,a4
  40:   0007c783                lbu a5,0(a5)
  44:   f7f9                    bnez    a5,12 <.L3>

0000000000000046 <.LBE2>:
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:7
}
  46:   0001                    nop
  48:   0001                    nop
  4a:   70a2                    ld  ra,40(sp)
  4c:   7402                    ld  s0,32(sp)
  4e:   6145                    addi    sp,sp,48
  50:   8082                    ret

0000000000000052 <main>:
main():
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:9

int main() {
  52:   1141                    addi    sp,sp,-16
  54:   e406                    sd  ra,8(sp)
  56:   e022                    sd  s0,0(sp)
  58:   0800                    addi    s0,sp,16
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:10
    printf("Hello world");
  5a:   000007b7                lui a5,0x0
  5e:   00078513                mv  a0,a5
  62:   00000097                auipc   ra,0x0
  66:   000080e7                jalr    ra # 62 <main+0x10>
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:11
    example_inline("Hello! I am inlined");
  6a:   000007b7                lui a5,0x0
  6e:   00078513                mv  a0,a5
  72:   00000097                auipc   ra,0x0
  76:   000080e7                jalr    ra # 72 <main+0x20>
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:13

    return 0;
  7a:   4781                    li  a5,0
/Users/cyao/test/main.c:14
}
  7c:   853e                    mv  a0,a5
  7e:   60a2                    ld  ra,8(sp)
  80:   6402                    ld  s0,0(sp)
  82:   0141                    addi    sp,sp,16
  84:   8082                    ret
```

PS. There are colors in the dissembled code

Comment: `--visualize-jumps=color` is also an option, to use different colors for different arrows.  This can be useful when branching gets denser, not like your trivial example.  e.g. my answer on [Better way than a terminal+objdump to read assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74793599) shows example output from some code with FP compare+branch (it's actually a bit messy to read without color, given the short branches on unordered next to another branch.)

Answer (score 1):

use **-Wa,-adhln** as option on gcc or g++ to produce a listing output to stdout.

-Wa,... is for command line options for the assembler part (execute in gcc/g++ after C/++ compilation). It invokes **as** internally (as.exe in Windows).
See

>as --help

as command line to see more help for the assembler tool inside gcc