# How do you compile high-level code to get assembly code?

Tags: assembly, compilation

I was wondering if there's some special way to compile high-level code (preferably from c/c++ or java) to get the corresponding assembly code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using GCC to produce readable assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[gcc can dump an assembly listing using -S switch](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html) - it will emit the assembly code to a file with a .s extension. For example, the following command:

```
gcc -O2 -S -c foo.c
```

will leave the generated assembly code on the file foo.s.

If you want to see the C code together with the assembly it was converted to, use a command line like this:

```
gcc -c -g -Wa,-a,-ad [other GCC options] foo.c > foo.lst
```

which will output the combined C/assembly listing to the file foo.lst.

Most compilers will support something similar to aid debugging the compiler itself. [For Visual C++, see this guide.](http://codegem.org/2008/10/generate-assembly-from-c-code-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Do you know if g++ has this function? If so how do you use it? thx

Comment: The option for g++ should be exactly the same

Comment: i was too lazy to read the man page, haha. guess i have to now. thx for the help everyone~~

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using gcc, http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html tells you to `gcc -O2 -S -c foo.c`

look at the manual/doco for your compiler - i m sure there is an option to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Those languages are quite different in that C and C++ are normally compiled to machine code, whereas Java uses a virtual machine. You cannot sensibly compile Java to assembly language (if you want to see the machine code, use a debugger), but with C or C++ it should be quite easy, depending on your compiler. For example, when using `gcc`, simply give it a `-S` option and it will produce an assembly code file instead of the object code.

Comment: There are Java compilers (like [gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/)) that do compile native code rather than JVM bytecode.  You could look at the generated assembly for those.

Answer (score 0):

Many compilers come with the option of listing the generated assembly code. For example, gcc has the -S option, which will stop the compilation before assembling and leave you with assembly files.