# GCC: Compile to assembly with clarified correspondence to code?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

When you break into the debugger in VS and open the disassembly window, each assembly fragment is displayed below it's corresponding code section (more or less). GCC with -S outputs only the stripped down assembly.

Is there an option in GCC to show some correspondence to the original code?

Source code is C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile your code with `gcc -g`, then you can disassemble with `objdump -S yourfile`. this will give you a disassembly interspersed with the source.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about debugging, in gdb use the disassemble command with a /m (mixed) flag:

```
(gdb) disas /m main
```

would disassemble main with C++ code interspersed with assembler, assuming the code is available and you compiled with the -g flag.

Answer (score 1):

Disassembly the object instead. The code given normally by -S is exactly what gcc generate for your code, without start code or other things that are put together by the linker. **Complement**: of course having debug infos in the object helps alot.

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc yourFile.C -S -fverbose-asm
```

Not exactly what you're looking for, but more useful than nothing.