# GCC/objdump: Generating compilable/buildable assembly (interspersed with C/C++) source?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, objdump

This is close to [Using GCC to produce readable assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly), but my context here is `avr-gcc` (and correspondingly, `avr-objdump`) for Atmel (though, I guess it would apply across the GCC board).

The thing is, I have a project of multiple .c and .cpp files; which ultimately get compiled into an executable, with the same name as the 'master' .cpp file. In this process, I can obtain assembly listing in two ways:

- I can instruct `gcc` to emit assembly listing source (see [Linux Assembly and Disassembly an Introduction](http://www.phiral.net/linuxasmone.htm)) using the `-S` switch; in this case, I get a file, with contents like:

  ```
  ...
  loop:
    push r14
    push r15
    push r16
    push r17
    push r28
    push r29
  /* prologue: function /
  / frame size = 0 */
    ldi r24,lo8(13)
    ldi r22,lo8(1)
    call digitalWrite
    rjmp .L2
  .L3:
    ldi r24,lo8(MyObj)
    ldi r25,hi8(MyObj)
    call _ZN16MYOBJ7connectEv
  .L2:
    ldi r24,lo8(MyObj)
    ldi r25,hi8(MyObj)
    call _ZN16MYOBJ11isConnectedEv
  ...
  ```

(*Haven't tried it yet; but I guess this code is compilable/buildable....*)

- I can inspect the final executable with, and instruct, `objdump` to emit assembly listing source using the `-S` switch; in this case, I get a file, with contents like:

  ```
  ...
  0000066a <init>:
  void init()
  {
          // this needs to be called before setup() or some functions won't
          // work there
          sei();
       66a:       78 94           sei
       66c:       83 b7           in      r24, 0x33       ; 51
       66e:       84 60           ori     r24, 0x04       ; 4
       670:       83 bf           out     0x33, r24       ; 51
  ...
  000006be <loop>:
       6be:       ef 92           push    r14
       6c0:       ff 92           push    r15
       6c2:       0f 93           push    r16
       6c4:       1f 93           push    r17
       6c6:       cf 93           push    r28
       6c8:       df 93           push    r29
       6ca:       8d e0           ldi     r24, 0x0D       ; 13
       6cc:       61 e0           ldi     r22, 0x01       ; 1
       6ce:       0e 94 23 02     call    0x446   ; 0x446 
       6d2:       04 c0           rjmp    .+8             ; 0x6dc 
       6d4:       8d ef           ldi     r24, 0xFD       ; 253
       6d6:       94 e0           ldi     r25, 0x04       ; 4
       6d8:       0e 94 25 06     call    0xc4a   ; 0xc4a <_ZN16MYOBJ7connectEv>
       6dc:       8d ef           ldi     r24, 0xFD       ; 253
       6de:       94 e0           ldi     r25, 0x04       ; 4
       6e0:       0e 94 21 06     call    0xc42   ; 0xc42 <_ZN16MYOBJ11isConnectedEv>
  ...
  ```

(*I did try to build this code, and it did fail - it reads the 'line numbers' as labels*)

Obviously, both listings (for the `loop` function, at least) represent the same assembly code; except:

- The `gcc` one (should) compile -- the `objdump` one does **not**
- The `objdump` one contains listings of all referred functions, which could be defined in files other than the 'master' (e.g., `digitalWrite`) -- the `gcc` one does **not**
- The `objdump` one contains original C/C++ source lines 'interspersed' with assembly (but only occasionally, and seemingly only for C files?) -- the `gcc` one does **not**

So, is there a way to obtain an assembly listing that would be 'compilable', however with all in-linked functions, and where source C/C++ code is (possibly, where appropriate) interspersed as comments (so they don't interfere with compilation of assembly file)? (*short of writing a parser for the output of `objdump`, that is :)*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the option `-fverbose-asm` to your gcc command line up there. (This is in the gcc manual, but it's documented under 'Code Gen Options')

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Spudd86 - just tried the `-fverbose-asm` option; however, it doesn't "include dependencies", nor keeps C/C++ source lines verbatim... It does generate a "_options passed_" list, and it will start noting some variables: `lds r24,MyObj  ;  MyObj._isConnected, MyObj._isConnected` - but I guess I'm more interested in having the starts of functions somehow delimited... Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The "dependencies" that you talk about often come from libraries or separate object files, so they don't have a source - they're just linked as binary code into the final executable. Since such code is not passed through the assembler, you will have to extract it using other ways - e.g. using objdump.

Maybe you should tell us what you *really* want to achieve because I don't see much point in such an exercise by itself.

Comment: Hi @Igor Skochinsky, thanks for the comment! You are correct - but in the case specifically of the AVR code, typically a lot of the objects files actually do come from source files. What I was hoping for, is to ultimately generate a "merged" assembly file, that I could use to generate more-less the same ELF executable as the project - then I intended to use this assembly listing in avr-gdb for debugging (as currently, I don't seem to be able to set gdb up, so it catches correct source lines during debugging). Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: I'd say the fixing debugging with gdb should be an easier (hopefully) and, in the end, more correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

The best I have been able to get is to use `-Wa,-ahl=outfile.s` instead of `-S`. It isn't compilable code though, but a listing file for diagnostic purposes; the compiled object file is emitted as usual.

Comment: Many thanks for that @Anonymous Coward - good to know that option! Cheers!