# Is there a way to compile the program without assembly in GCC?

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, object-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using GCC to produce readable assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly)

For example, when I try:

gcc -c myprogram

it will give me an object file, which is in binary form. What I would like to get is just an assembly file (right before it is processed by an assembler to produce the object file). Is there a way to do it in gcc?

Comment: Specifically, you want the second and subsequent answers (at time of writing), since the accepted answer assembles and then disassembles.

Answer (score 8):

just write `gcc -S file.c`, and you will get file.s which is assembly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It's -S. See the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).