# How to make objdump show assembly of sections only appeared in source code?

Tags: c, gcc, objdump

I would like to produce assemblies like the one in the answer of this question [Using GCC to produce readable assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly)

for simple test code: test.c

```
void main(){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   printf("%d\n",i);
   }
}
```

gcc command : `gcc -g test.c -o test.o`

objdump command: `objdump -d -M intel -S test.o`

But what i got is assemblies  starts with .init section 
   `080482bc<_init>:` and end with .fini section `080484cc<_fini>`

which i do not want them to be shown.

why is this happening ? and how can i avoid showing sections that are not in the source file?

Comment: You can use grep (assuming you are using Linux) to search the disassembly for the section you want to see, such as:
` objdump -D test.out | grep -A20 main.: `
This will only show you the first 20 lines from the main section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now you're creating an executable file and not an object file. The executable file of course contains lot of extra sections.

If you want to create an object file, use the `-c` flag to GCC.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify sections using `-j` option.

So `objdump -d executable -j .text -j .plt` will only show disassembly from .text and .plt sections.