# How to disassemble a .lib static library?

Tags: c, static-libraries, disassembly

I have written this simple library in c:

library.h:

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

library.c:

```
#include "library.h"
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

I compiled it with cl.exe (visual studio 2012) using these commands:

```
cl /c /EHsc library.cpp
lib library.obj
```

which compiled it as a static link .lib library file. Now I would like to have a look at how the compiler generated the assembly code, for learning/academic purposes. Please note, I don't want to decompile it, I just want to read the generated assembly. I have tried to open the .lib with w32dasm but I get a lot of strange symbols and it looks like the tool is unable to read the file. I've HAVE done a similar task with a *dynamic* link library (generated from the same source) and it worked; in that I was able to view the assembly code using w32dasm. So, my question is: is possible to view the assembly code of a static link library as you can do with a dynamic link library? If so, what would be the correct tool to use, since w32dasm does not appear to be the correct tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using GCC to produce readable assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly)

Comment: @usmcs thank you for solved my english misspells

Comment: @HansPassant does objdump work under windows?

Comment: Use the -S option so objdump is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @HansPassant do you mean gcc -S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically a little bit different because its not going to disassemble the `.lib` file, but for most purposes should be good enough:

You can use `/FA` switch, as described in detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). More precisely you will probably want to use `/FAs` which should produce `.asm` file for each source file containing both assembly and source code, which is helpful for reference. For example if you add this to your `cl` command:

```
cl /c /EHsc /FAs library.cpp
```

This should, in addition to its normal function, create a file `library.asm`. This file can possibly contain a lot of stuff, so searching through it is a good idea.

If you are using Visual Studio IDE you can also set a breakpoint, start debugging and then right click a source line and choose *Go To Disassembly*. This option shows up in the context menu only during debugging and is active only during a break, this is why setting up a breakpoint is useful, but you can also break manually.

Answer (score 7):

If you do want to disassemble the library instead of looking at the compiler-generated assembler, you can use the [`DUMPBIN` tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx):

```
dumpbin /disasm library.lib
```

[IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) can also handle static libraries and object files (and dozens of other file formats). Disclaimer: I work for Hex-Rays.