# How do pointers work "under the hood" in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Take a simple program like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char p;
    char *q;

    q = &p;

    return 0;
}
```

How is `&p` determined? Does the compiler calculate all such references before-hand or is it done at runtime? If at runtime, is there some table of variables or something where it looks these things up? Does the OS keep track of them and it just asks the OS?

My question may not even make sense in the context of the correct explanation, so feel free to set me straight.

Comment: You should look at the machine code that your compiler generates. If you don't understand machine code, no answer is going to be terribly meaningful to you, so that would be something to start learning about.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Kerrek, I completely forgot that there were assembly instructions for such things. For any future readers, here's a link to using `objdump` to get the assembly code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler cannot know the full address of `p` at compile-time because a function can be called multiple times by different callers, and `p` can have different values.

Of course, the compiler has to know how to *calculate* the address of `p` at run-time, not only for the address-of operator, but simply in order to generate code that works with the `p` variable. On a regular architecture, local variables like `p` are allocated on the *stack*, i.e. in a position with fixed offset relative to the address of the current stack frame.

Thus, the line `q = &p` simply stores into `q` (another local variable allocated on the stack) the address `p` has in the current stack frame.

Note that in general, what the compiler does or doesn't know is implementation-dependent. For example, an optimizing compiler might very well optimize away your entire `main` after analyzing that its actions have no observable effect. The above is written under the assumption of a mainstream architecture and compiler, and a non-static function (other than `main`) that may be invoked by multiple callers.

Comment: I see. I guess I just forgot about this, but basically it would use `lea` (load effective address) in the assembly code, with an offset determined by the type?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius The offset would be determined at compile-time; for example, the variable `p` might get offset 0, the variable `q` offset 4. Variables stored in registers wouldn't get an offset at all, etc. If you understand assembly, simply look at the assembly output - under GCC you get it with `gcc -S foo.c`.

Answer (score 6):

> How is `&p` determined? Does the compiler calculate all such references before-hand or is it done at runtime?

This is an implementation detail of the compiler. Different compilers can choose different techniques depending on the kind of operating system they are generating code for and the whims of the compiler writer.

Let me describe for you how this is typically done on a modern operating system like Windows.

When the process starts up, the operating system gives the process a *virtual address space*, of, let's say 2GB.  Of that 2GB, a 1MB section of it is set aside as "the stack" for the main thread.   The stack is a region of memory where everything "below" the current stack pointer is "in use", and everything in that 1MB section "above" it is "free".  How the operating system chooses which 1MB chunk of virtual address space is the stack is an implementation detail of Windows.

(Aside: whether the free space is at the "top" or "bottom" of the stack, whether the "valid" space grows "up" or "down" is also an implementation detail. Different operating systems on different chips do it differently. Let's suppose the stack grows from high addresses to low addresses.)

The operating system ensures that when `main` is invoked, the register `ESP` contains the address of the dividing line between the valid and free portions of the stack.

(Aside: again, whether the `ESP` is the address of the first *valid* point or the first *free* point is an implementation detail.)

The compiler generates code for `main` that *pushes* the stack pointer by lets say five bytes, by subtracting from it if the stack is growing "down". It decreases by five because it needs one byte for `p` and four for `q`. So the stack pointer changes; there are now five more "valid" bytes and five fewer "free" bytes.

Let's say that `q` is the memory that is now in `ESP` through `ESP+3` and  `p` is the memory now in `ESP+4`.  To assign the address of `p` to `q`, the compiler generates code that copies the four byte *value* `ESP+4` into the *locations* `ESP` through `ESP+3`.

(Aside: Note that it is highly likely that the compiler lays out the stack so that everything that has its address taken is on an `ESP+offset` value that is divisible by four. Some chips have requirements that addresses be divisible by pointer size. Again, this is an implementation detail.)

**If you do not understand the difference between an address used as a value and an address used as a storage location, figure that out**.  Without understanding that key difference you will not be successful in C.

That's one way it could work but like I said, different compilers can choose to do it differently as they see fit.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this. You tied together a bunch of different aspects of this very well. One small thing: you perhaps should change it to "one byte for `p` and four for `q`" if you want to mirror the program I posted above.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: You're right, I missed that `p` was `char`.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: And you are very welcome! To learn more, I recommend that you compile some programs *with all optimizations disabled* and then examine the resulting assembly code in a debugger. You will very quickly see how the compiler works its magic.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an *extraordinarily* difficult question to answer in full generality because it's massively complicated by [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) and [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29).

The short answer is that the compiler basically deals in terms of offsets from some “base”, which is decided by the runtime loader when you execute your program. Your variables, `p` and `q`, will appear very close to the “bottom” of the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (although the stack base is usually very high in VM and it grows “down”).

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a variable with automatic storage.  It lives only as long as the function it is in lives.  Every time its function is called memory for it is taken from the stack, therefore, its address can change and is not known until runtime.

Comment: You mean automatic storage duration?

Comment: @ouah Yes.  Automatic duration/storage.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In any function, the function arguments and the local variables are allocated on the stack, after the position (program counter) of the last function at the point where it calls the current function. How these variables get allocated on the stack and then deallocated when returning from the function, is taken care of by the compiler during compile time.

For e.g. for this case, p (1 byte) could be allocated first on the stack followed by q (4 bytes for 32-bit architecture). The code assigns the address of p to q. The address of p naturally then is 5 added or subtracted from the the last value of the stack pointer. Well, something like that, depends on how the value of the stack pointer is updated and whether the stack grows upwards or downwards.

How the return value is passed back to the calling function is something that I'm not certain of, but I'm guessing that it is passed through the registers and not the stack. So, when the return is called, the underlying assembly code should deallocate p and q, place zero into the register, then return to the last position of the caller function. Of course, in this case, it is the main function, so it is more complicated in that, it causes the OS to terminate the process. But in other cases, it just goes back to the calling function.

In ANSI C, all the local variables should be placed at the top of the function and is allocated once into the stack when entering the function and deallocated when returning from the function. In C++ or later versions of C, this becomes more complicated when local variables can also be declared inside blocks (like if-else or while statement blocks). In this case, the local variable is allocated onto the stack when entering the block and deallocated when leaving the block.

In all cases, the address of a local variable is always a fixed number added or subtracted from the stack pointer (as calculated by the compiler, relative to the containing block) and the size of the variable is determined from the variable type.

However, `static` local variables and global variables are different in C. These are allocated in fixed locations in the memory, and thus there's a fixed address for them (or a fixed offset relative to the process' boundary), which is calculated by the linker.

Yet a third variety is memory allocated on the heap using malloc/new and free/delete. I think this discussion would be too lengthy if we include that as well.

That said, my description is only for a typical hardware architecture and OS. All of these are also dependent on a wide variety of things, as mentioned by Emmet.

Answer (score 1):

Address of a local variable cannot be completely calculated at compile time. Local variables are typically allocated in the stack. When called, each function allocates a *stack frame* - a single continuous block of memory in which it stores all its local variables. The physical location of the stack frame in memory cannot be predicted at compile time. It will only become known at run-time. The beginning of each stack frame is typically stored at run-time in a dedicated processor register, like `ebp` on Intel platform.

Meanwhile, the internal memory layout of a stack frame is pre-determined by the compiler at compile-time, i.e. it is the compiler who decides how local variables will be laid out inside the stack frame. This means that the compiler knows the local offset of each local variable inside the stack frame.

Put this all together and we get that the exact absolute address of a local variable is *the sum* of the address of the stack frame itself (the run-time component) and the offset of this variable inside that frame (the compile-time component).

This is basically exactly what the compiled code for

```
q = &p;
```

will do. It will take the current value of the stack frame register, add some compile-time constant to it (offset of `p`) and store the result in `q`.