# Need help understanding GCC assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compilation

For my homework assignment I am supposed to convert this C code

```
 #define UPPER 15
 const int lower = 12;

 int sum = 0;

 int main(void) {
   int i;
   for (i = lower; i < UPPER; i++) {
     sum += i;
   }
   return sum;
 }
```

into gcc assembly. I already compiled it to first study the code before doing it per hand (obviously translating by hand is going to look much differently). This is the assembler code I received:

```
.file   "upper.c"
.globl  lower
.section    .rodata
.align 4
.type   lower, @object
.size   lower, 4
    lower:
.long   12
.globl  sum
.bss
.align 4
.type   sum, @object
.size   sum, 4
     sum:
.zero   4
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
    main:
    .LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
movl    $12, -4(%rbp)
jmp .L2
    .L3:
movl    sum(%rip), %edx
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
addl    %edx, %eax
movl    %eax, sum(%rip)
addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    .L2:
cmpl    $14, -4(%rbp)
jle .L3
movl    sum(%rip), %eax
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
    .LFE0:
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Now I was wondering if someone could give me a few examples like

- where the constructors i, lower, upper and sum are located it in code
- where some of the expressions i = lower or i < UPPER are located
- where the for-loop starts

and such things so I can then get an idea of how the assembler code is constructed. Thank you!

Comment: Compile your code with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S `

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1289907/1101537) describes how to get readable disassembly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using GCC to produce readable assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly)

Comment: @nos: Thank you - that is already a little better with the comments on the side.

Comment: @alexander: I already compiled the code into disassembly too, however, I don't really understand that either: What do the different sections stand for ("Disassembly section of .plt, .init, etc) and what do the four blocks portray in for ex:   4003c0:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp

Comment: @eva, that sections is used by gcc compiler to prepare C-program runtime environment before  it enter main(): initialize global variables (like 'int sum = 0' - .init), hold constant variables (.const) and do another things. Just skip them to main() to see how main() is compiled into assembly.

Comment: See the post [Linux x86 Program Start Up or - How the heck do we get to main()?](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) to understand how global variables get initialized in C-programs. I don't understand your goals. What do you want to achieve: write custom asm-program for linux or understand C-runtime background?

Comment: @alexander: My goal is to compile the C code into gcc assemlby by hand. That is why I wanted someone to point out a few of the things I listed (i, sum, lower, i = lower, etc) in the already compiled assembler so I could get the hang of it. Your post was already really helpful understanding the structure of assembly but could you also point out a couple of the things in my code - it is still a little unclear to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly you question, here is the answers:

Q: where the constructors i, lower, upper and sum are located it in code?

`lower` is located inside `.rodata` section (readonly data section). It's value is initialized by linux loader during program loading stage to the value `.long 12`. `lower` constructor is a linux loader. It just loads `lower` value from binary image.

```
.globl  lower
.section    .rodata
.align 4
.type   lower, @object
.size   lower, 4
    lower:
.long   12
```

`sum` is located inside `.bss` section (data segment containing statically-allocated variables). It's value is initialized by `_init` function what gets called when program execution begins. It's value is zero (`.zero 4`). Every variable located inside `.bss` section has zero as initial value ([link to wiki's article for .bss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)).

```
.globl  sum
.bss
.align 4
.type   sum, @object
.size   sum, 4
     sum:
.zero   4
```

`upper` is a constant. The compiler did not put it's declaration into assembly. There is a reference to `upper-1` (as `$14`) here:

```
    .L2:
cmpl    $14, -4(%rbp)
```

`i` is a on stack temporary variable. It's value is accessed using addresses relative `%rbp` (`%rbp` is a pointer to current function stack frame). The is no explicit declaration of `i` into assembly. There is no explicit stack reservation for `i` (no instruction like `sub $0x8,%rsp` at main preamble), I think, because main doesn't call another functions. Here is code for `i` initialization (note compiler knows that `lower` initial value is `$12` and removes access to `lower` during `i` initialization):

```
movl    $12, -4(%rbp)
```

Q: where some of the expressions i = lower or i < UPPER are located

`i = lower`:

```
movl    $12, -4(%rbp)
jmp .L2
```

`i < UPPER`:

```
    .L2:
cmpl    $14, -4(%rbp)
jle .L3
```

`i++`:

```
addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
```

`sum += i;`:

```
movl    sum(%rip), %edx
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
addl    %edx, %eax
movl    %eax, sum(%rip)
```

`return sum;` (`%eax` register is used to hold function return value - more about this: [X86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)):

```
jle .L3
movl    sum(%rip), %eax
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
```

Q: where the for-loop starts

it start here:

```
movl    $12, -4(%rbp)
jmp .L2
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you so much! I noticed due to your answer that I had misinterpreted a lot in the code but now it is much clearer!