# Map assemly to C source code

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction

Is there anyway using a C compiler such as GCC or clang to generate assembly output that has the C code mapped to the assembly output (so that it possible to see what block of assembly represent in C code) on a Linux system? I am trying to understand what the output of a piece of C code is with O3 enabled but I am having difficult time since my knowledge of assembly is lacking.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly

Comment: use `-S` options with GCC, TCC, BCC

Comment: The quickest way is to use [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#) it even uses color to link the C code to assembly. You will have to use `-x c` though but that is not too hard. Previously I would have linked you to [Online C++ compiler and evaluator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) but sadly was recently deleted.

Comment: You can either go the `objdump` route, or you can tell gcc to generate a listings file (as described [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Use `-S` option with `gcc` to generate the assembly file output.

> gcc -S file.c

**EDIT:**

If you want to view both `assembly` output and `C` code side-by-side, use `gdb -tui a.out`:

> (gdb) layout split

The layout split command divides the window into two parts - one of them displaying the source code, the other one the corresponding assembly.

Comment: The OP wants both C and assembly in the output. `-S` does not do that AFAIK.

Comment: @Michael Okay added that to my edit.