# C: Performant temporary variables to avoid frequent typecasting

Tags: c, performance, variables, temporary

`((My_LengthilyNamedClass *)this)->someMember`

...I am getting tired of these appearing all over my codebase, many times even within the same function.

What is the appropriate way to handle such things in C? I'm aware that copying this to a correctly-typed stack/automatic variable with a shorter name is one approach to avoid the casts, but I suppose this would cause additional, potentially unnecessary stack allocations.

Can one use a `define` inside of individual functions, to make this easier? Are `define`s the way to go? As this is code for a real-time processing framework, and these things appear everywhere, I'd ideally like to stick to whatever's most performant.

Comment: Temp variables do not always cause overhead see [Do temp variables slow down my program?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26949569/1708801)

Comment: Use an inline function.

Comment: BTW what's the original type of `this` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb it's `void * const`

Comment: Could you provide more context. If you're doing that a lot I'm surprised.

Comment: @DanAllen A generic object pointer of type `void *` doesn't have any members, so I'm guessing it is cast to a pointer to an object with a type such as `struct MyClass`, which has the necessary "class" member.

Comment: @DanAllen It could be a Variant-style object, or a manual implementation of polymorphism

Comment: @DanAllen Spot on, what Matt McNabb said - a manual implementation of polymorphism.

Comment: @NickWiggill: The answer is in the question then. Assign a local variable. It will (at worst) have a vanishingly small effect on performance. In all likelihood get optimized away given your cast is a logical step but computationally a no-op. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."  (Knuth)

Comment: @DanAllen Like so many others, misquoting what Knuth actually said. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @NickWiggill: Whether the precise words are right is debatable. There are variations. What is true is making many casts to save a local variable is the practice he was referring to. Have fun. "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time. Premature Optimization is the root of all evil." http://sbel.wisc.edu/Courses/ME964/Literature/knuthProgramming1974.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers are pretty good at optimizing. I think you would have no problems with:

```
My_LengthilyNamedClass *const ptr = this;
```

If you are really paranoid you could use a macro:

```
#define THIS ((My_LengthilyNamedClass *)this)

THIS->someMember = 5;

#undef THIS
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have many of these casts, you can change:

```
((My_LengthilyNamedClass *)this)->someMember
```

to

```
My_LengthilyNamedClass *that = (My_LengthilyNamedClass *) this;
```

/* ... */

```
that->someMember
```