# Will an instant return function call compile to a "nop" instruction?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, compilation

Say I have a function:

```
void foo ( int bar ){
    return;
}
```

will this compile to a `nop` instruction?

Comment: That's a pretty easy thing for you to test, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Why should there be a `nop` where there could be nothing?

Comment: [Using GCC to produce readable assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly)

Comment: There are online tools for this as well.  See: http://goo.gl/iik1PE

Answer (score 6):

It's not specified what should be done by the c++ standard. But I'd say any decent compiler would optimize out such code and not even leave a `nop` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Modern compilers emit `nop`-like instructions for some purpose - commonly for alignment (on many architectures branches are executed faster if the target is aligned to - say - 16 bytes) or to wait for some operations to complete (IIRC on IA64 you *must* wait some number of cycles before using the result of some opcodes, so either you have something else to do or you have to emit `nop`s).

Now, either we are in this case or most probably no `nop` will be emitted. For a function like this you can expect the regular stack frame setup followed by the cleanup for non optimized builds, or a plain `ret` (plus the stack cleanup code if mandated by the calling convention) in optimized ones.

Even better, if the compiler is smart enough and the definition of the function is known when compiling the call site (so, this is a `static` function, an `inline` one or link time code generation is enabled) the call may be omitted altogether, and there may remain no trace of the function code in the final executable.