# Where to look up assembly operators?

Tags: gcc, assembly, g++

I'm using g++ with the -S option, and I'm getting lots of operators I don't know or understand, and google is not leading me to a result. Some examples are `fldt`, `fstpl`, and I don't come across a quick reference to what it does. It seems odd that I can't find documentation for it, is there a place for me to look that is more complete than trying to google assembly operators? What are some good resources?

Comment: The are instructiins, not operators. And yes, every single one of them will be explained in the manufacturer's documentation. I'm assuming x86 so download Intel's assembly documentation, or one of the many other instruction lists. Just note that some commands have several forms and may have letters added to them, like fld

Comment: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/  has an instruction set reference based on the Intel manuals. ATT syntax uses instruction mnemonics that may end with an additional `l`, `t`, `w` `b` `q` for the size. In your case you want to look at the instructions FLD and FSTP.

Comment: I usually refer to this one: x86.renejeschke.de

Comment: You can get _GCC_ to dump the `-S` output as Intel syntax by adding the `-masm=intel` option.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the reference manual may be the best investment. What you could also do is produce Intel syntax ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly))

```
> gcc -g -c test.c
> objdump -d -M intel -S test.o > test.asm
```

The resulting test.asm file is not an assembly file that can be assembled by an assembler but can be useful in studying your program. And assuming you have access to Visual Studio, you can open test.asm with Visual Studio and install the extension AsmDude to get quick feedback on what the instructions do.

Comment: No, gcc's intel syntax output can of course also be assembled with the GNU assembler.

Comment: @fuz could you clarify the no. My sentence just states that the resulting test.asm may offend your assembler a bit.

Comment: It doesn't actually “offend” the assembler. The GNU assembler can be switched between AT&T and Intel mode.

Comment: @fuz I mean objdump does not generate a "true" asm file, never mind.

Comment: Oh sorry, I totally misread your question. I somehow read that you want to pass `-masm=intel` to gcc. Objection withdrawn.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical reference for all of this is the *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual.* You can find it on the Intel website. I am not going to provide a link as they frequently shift around their page structure.

Note that this manual is comprehensive and very detailed, for a beginner it might be a bit overwhelming. Read this manual carefully, many instructions have fairly subtle behaviour.

Lastly, note that `g++` emits assembly in *AT&T-syntax.* Among other things, this means that most instructions with more than one operand have their operands flipped, for example, the instruction `add %ax,%bx` adds `ax` to `bx` and stores the result in `bx`.