# Getting assember output from GCC/Clang in LTO mode

Tags: gcc, assembly, clang, lto

Normally, one can [get GCC's optimized assembler output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) from a source file using the `-S` flag in GCC and Clang, as in the following example.

```
gcc -O3 -S -c -o foo.s foo.c
```

But suppose I compile all of my source files using `-O3 -flto` to enable link-time whole-program optimizations and want to see the final compiler-generated optimized assembly for a function, and/or see where/how code gets inlined.

The result of compiling is a bunch of `.o` files which are really IR files disguised as object files, as expected. In linking an executable or shared library, these are then smushed together, optimized as a whole, and then compiled into the target binary.

But what if I want assembly output from this procedure? That is, the assembly source that results *after* link-time optimizations, during the compilation of IR to assembly, and before the actual assembly and linkage into the final executable.

**I tried simply adding a `-S` flag to the link step, but that didn't really work.**

I know disassembling the executable is possible, even interleaving with source, but sometimes it's nicer to look at actual compiler-generated assembly, especially with `-fverbose-asm`.

Comment: You can always disassemble; with `-g` there are labels on every function, and block -> source-line-number debug info that lets `objdump -drwC -S -l` [interleave disassembly with source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly).  Worth a try, IDK if that works.  Not as nice as `gcc -S -fverbose-asm` to have named outputs, though.

Comment: Disassembly is what I currently do, but I was wondering if there is any way to do it without needing to do that :c (i.e. a big fat assembly file that, itself, can be assembled into the final binary)

Comment: In the LLVM case, would `llvm-link`'ing all of the "object" files together before passing `-S` work?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I upvoted the question and posted a workaround as a comment!

Comment: I don't have Clang on me at the moment to test it, but I think it would work. However, that's LLVM-specific, and I want to find a unified solution, if possible.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out, I'm trying to get ASM output in godbolt with clang but -flto messes it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For GCC just add `-save-temps` to linker command:

```
$ gcc -flto -save-temps ... *.o -o bin/libsortcheck.so
$ ls -1
...
libsortcheck.so.ltrans0.s
```

For Clang the situation is more complicated. In case you use GNU ld (default or `-fuse-ld=ld`) or Gold linker (enabled via `-fuse-ld=gold`), you need to run with `-Wl,-plugin-opt=emit-asm`:

```
$ clang tmp.c -flto -Wl,-plugin-opt=emit-asm -o tmp.s
```

For [newer (11+) versions](https://reviews.llvm.org/D77231) of LLD linker (enabled via `-fuse-ld=lld`) you can generate asm with `-Wl,--lto-emit-asm`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me on `clang`, but it seems to be getting there. Adding that option seems to make it emit `.bc` and `.ii` for individual sources, but nothing yet for the actual binary. The closest I got was with `-Wl,-plugin-opt=save-temps`, which output `*.{preopt,internalize,opt,precodegen}.bc` files and a `*.lto.o`, but no assembly source.

Comment: @MonatheMonad thanks for the feedback, for some reason I thought the question was GCC-only. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Any final binaries built from the resulting monolithic assembly file should be effectively identical to ones built "normally" (i.e. without `-Wl,-plugin-opt=emit-asm`), as there is nothing left to do but assembly and linkage, right? I want to make this assembly generation a side-effect of some debug builds, and I wonder whether a simple `clang -shared -o foo.so foo.so.s` would suffice.

Comment: @MonatheMonad this is definitely true for GCC - if you look at `strace` you can see that it actually assembles the exact same ltrans0.s file which is generated under `-save-temps`. For Clang the situation is less clear, I'll look into this later.

Comment: @MonatheMonad judging from the code for Clang situation seems to be the same but I'd do some verification to be sure (e.g. compare binaries for both LTO flows).