# Caching the end iterator - Good idea or Bad Idea?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

Generally speaking is it a good idea to cache an end iterator (specifically STL containers) for efficiency and speed purposes? such as in the following bit of code:

```
std::vector<int> vint;
const std::vector<int>::const_iterator end = vint.end();
std::vector<int>::iterator it = vint.begin();

while (it != end)
{
   ....
   ++it;
}
```

Under what conditions would the end value be invalidated? would erasing from the container cause end to be invalidated in ***all*** STL containers or just some?

Comment: First ask yourself, does your profiler tell you that the call to std::vector<int>::end() cost a significant amount of processing time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the simple case of a `vector`, the `end` iterator will change when you add or remove elements from the container; though, it's usually safest to assume that if you mutate the container while iterating over it, **all** iterators to it become invalid. Iterators may be implemented differently in any given STL implementation.

With regard to caching the `end` iterator -- it's certainly valid to cache it, but to find out if it is actually faster in your case, the best bet is for you to profile your code and see. While retrieving the `end` iterator from a `vector` is likely a fast implementation with a recent STL library and compiler, I *have* worked on past projects where caching the `end` iterator gave us a significant speed boost. (This was on the PlayStation 2, so do take with a grain of salt.)

Answer (score 4):

If we are talking about efficiency and speed: caching the end iterator is unnecessary because of compiler optimizations and inlining.

Comment: Is it really ? Most of the advices I have seen preaching for using the STL algorithms (like `for_each`) were that it would cache the `end` iterator so it doesn't get computed at each iteration.

Comment: @Matthieu: iterators are not guaranteed to survive modification of some containers (e.g. resizing vector invalidates *all* iterators to the vector). for_each doesn't give function object access to the iterator, the container can't be changed, thus it is OK to cache the iterator. but if you trick the systems and from the function object modify the container in a way that invalidates the iterators, then obviously it would lead to *undefined behavior*, likely crash, when accessing container over the now invalid iterator.

Comment: Actually, resizing a vector only invalidates the iterators if a reallocation occurs, and you can make sure it doesn't if you resize only up to the capacity. But the point of my question remains, I am unsure that the compiler is able to optimize the computation of `end()` out of the loop, even if inlined the compiler as a priori no way of knowing if the value is likely to get modified by the operations within the loop as far as I know. But then I don't know much about compiler optmizations, thus my question :)

Comment: @Matthieu: You can take a look at generated code for your loop (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840321/how-can-i-see-the-assembly-code-for-a-c-program). There you will find the difference between various approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Erasing from a container over which you are currently iterating is always a bad idea. The actual caching of your end iterator is not going to change that.

h.

Comment: Not at all, if you do it properly. The 'erase' member of std::vector, for instance, returns an appropriate new iterator. So as long as you write your code correctly (that is, remember that other iterators are now invalid) you will have no problems erasing from a container you are iterating over.

Answer (score 2):

> Generally speaking is it a good idea
>   to cache an end iterator (specifically
>   STL containers) for efficiency and
>   speed purposes?

If you use the STL container algorithms the caching of the end iterator is happens anyway (as you pass the result of container.end() as a parameter).

If you modify the memory of the container (insert/remove elements) it's a bad bad idea.

Also, caching for efficiency rarely makes much sense: in most cases the end() is inlined by the compiler, and when it is not, it is very probable that your efficiency doesn't hang on the end() result being cached. YMMV though.

Answer (score 2):

The invalidation rules (for iterators) is defined very explicitly for each type of container. I find the SGI site very useful http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html

Specifically for vectors I find:

> [5] A vector's iterators are invalidated when its memory is reallocated. Additionally, inserting or deleting an element in the middle of a vector invalidates all iterators that point to elements following the insertion or deletion point. It follows that you can prevent a vector's iterators from being invalidated if you use reserve() to preallocate as much memory as the vector will ever use, and if all insertions and deletions are at the vector's end.

Answer (score 1):

I often use this style for iterating containers:

```
// typedef std::vector<Person> Persons;
Persons::iterator it = persons.begin(), end = persons.end();
for (; it != end; ++it)
{
    Person & person = *it;
    // ...
}
```

Erasing an element from a vector invalidates all iterators after the erased position.

I'm not certain about the other container types. In any case I think it would be safe to assume that all iterators become invalid after an erase. If you really need very specific information then you can always look it up. I rarely need this because because of my rather conservative coding style.

Answer (score 1):

In general it should not matter if you cache the end iterator.  If you feel it does matter, then you should already be using a profiler on your code and would be able to profile both variations.  I'd suspect it could differ depending upon the container type - but a profiler would be the only way to know for sure given your compiler, optimizations and STL vendor.

Answer (score 0):

It really, really depends of what are you doing in the `...` code.

If the compiler can prove that `vint.end()` is not going to change then it might not matter, but you are at the mercy of the compiler optimizations then and how clear is the `...` code.

Your approach is the one that helps the compiler the most, you are promising that the `end` iterator will not be invalidated and that you are not going to modify the element in `end` (which is invalid any way). You cannot be more explicit than this about what you promise you will do in `...`.

It is 2019, and for-range loops are basically equivalent to your code: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {

        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement

    }
}
```

which incidentally means that if you were not really interested in `it`, but in `*it`, you can put an end (no pun intended) to the dilemma and just write:

```
std::vector<int> vint;
for(auto&& e : vint)
{
   .... // use `e` instead of `*it`.
}
```