# Past-the-end iterator invalidation in C++11

Tags: c++, iterator

The most popular post on C++ [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438086/985943) claims that it's not clear if the past-the-end iterators (i.e., those returned by `end()`, `cend()`, `rend()`, and `crend()`) are invalidated according to the same rules as normal iterators, which point to elements in the container. These claims, made for both 2003 and 2011 C++, defer to a post discussing [End iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6440392/985943), where the accepted answer suggests that the 2003 standard is ambiguous on the matter. This conclusion is based on a comment in 23.1/10 (in the context of `swap()`) that seems to imply that when the spec does not explicitly mention invalidation of past-the-end iterators, they may be invalidated.

A comment on that post's question (by mike-seymour) suggests that C++11 is unambiguous on this matter, in the case of `deque`s. My question is about all containers:

- In C++11, are there any container operations that may invalidate a past-the-end iterator, and where this behavior is ambiguous in the language specification?

Said differently,

- Can I trust the validity of a past-the-end iterator after performing a container operation that does not say it may invalidate the past-the-end iterators?

Comment: You can trust the validity of past-the-end iterator after performing an operation that does not invalidate any iterator. For all other cases, I would not know, I don't really care: reobtain the iterator (which is a constant time operation) and there is no need to worry about whether that particular iterator is invalidated or not...

Comment: There are certainly operations that may invalidate an end iterator.  `vector::erase`, for example, "invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of erasure."  The end iterator is necessarily "after the point of erasure."

Comment: @dribeas: Thanks for your workaround; I'm sure it's optimal in almost every situation, especially given compiler inlining, etc. There is anecdotal evidence (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3084109/985943) that you might get performance benefits from caching the past-the-end pointers; indeed this motivated my question.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Agreed. The standard is unambiguous here because the end iterator is [defined somewhere to be] after the point of erasure. How about `vector::reserve()`, 23.3.6.3/5 (I have rev. n3337), "Reallocation invalidates all the...iterators referring to the elements in the sequence," and this list does not include the past-the-end iterators, which by definition do not point to elements in the sequence. Yet, the SGI implementation invalidates _all_ iterators, presumably the past-the-end ones too [http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html#5]. More: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1624961/985943

Comment: That is assuredly a defect in the C++11 specification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My question is about all containers:
>
> - In C++11, are there any container operations that may invalidate a past-the-end iterator, and where this behavior is ambiguous in the
>   language specification?

I am not sure what you mean with "where this behavior is ambiguous in the language specification", but there certainly are operations that invalidate past-the-end iterators (like insert into a `std::vector` or `std::string`).

> Said differently,
>
> - Can I trust the validity of a past-the-end iterator after performing a container operation that does not say it may invalidate
>   the past-the-end iterators?

You can trust the past-the-end iterator like any other iterator: Any operation that does not (potentially) invalidate iterators won't invalidate them. Except for the possibility of the standard sporting a bug, that is all operations where it doesn't say that they (potentially) invalidate operators.

Comment: What about the quote for `reserve` in the comment-to-the-question: `"Reallocation invalidates all the...iterators referring to the elements in the sequence,"`? Would you say that's definitely a defect in the standard?

Comment: @Mark: It probably is. Common sense would dictate that for many containers, invalidating iterators into the sequence will necessarily also invalidate the end iterator. (However, I am about as far away from a language lawyer as high-rep C++ tag user come, so take this with a grain of salt.)

Comment: Actually cppreference.com does talk about end() iterator's invalidation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624474/199150 (below)

Comment: "past-the-end operators" - mistake?

Comment: @Koe: Indeed! Thanks, I fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to trust it if the standard says the operation will not invalidate iterators. Anything else should be treated as a bug in the standard library implementation.

Comment: Personally I agree that a negative answer to my (second) question should mean a bug in the standard. And I agree with your response, but I really was hoping you could show that the inverse to what you said was false. That is, 'You should be able to trust that no iterator, including past-the-end iterators, are invalidated by a container operation if the standard doesn't say they are.'

Answer (score 1):

Regarding end iterator's invalidation rules, there is a mention in [cppreference.com#Iterator_invalidation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Iterator_invalidation).

The relevant lines are:

> The past-the-end iterator deserves particular mention. In general this iterator is invalidated as though it were a normal iterator to a non-erased element. So std::set::end is never invalidated, std::unordered_set::end is invalidated only on rehash, std::vector::end is always invalidated (since it is always after the modified elements), and so on.
>
> There is one exception: an erasure which deletes the last element of a std::deque does invalidate the past-the-end iterator, even though it is not an erased element of the container (or an element at all). Combined with the general rules for std::deque iterators, the net result is that the only modifying operation which does not invalidate std::deque::end is an erasure which deletes the first element, but not the last.

Also see a test with std::set's end() - https://godbolt.org/z/5ecdqYod3.

Answer (score 0):

At least in GCC end iterator gets invalidated for std::map:

```
#include <set>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main() {
  std::set<int> a;
  a.insert(1);
  std::set<int>::reverse_iterator rit(a.rbegin());
  ++rit;
  assert(rit==a.rend());
  a.erase(a.begin());
  assert(a.rend()==rit); // FAIL
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but flawed. `.rend()` returns an iterator-adaptor. Specifically, the one that adapts `a.begin()`, NOT `a.end()`, so there is no contradiction. `rend()` by definition adapts `begin()` and that iterator was invalidated, explicitly by the `erase`.

Comment: Counter example to demonstrate the point: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a195ac32db336f2. Same goes for regular iterators http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e80855c3b88422a and even in the case of removing the single element: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e06c5188e46d52b6 like your original example