# Ratio of Source Code / Machine Language

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

For a Computer Science assignment, I am supposed to write a small program in any language and determine the ratio of source code instructions to compiled machine code instructions - how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your compiler you can use a switch to also create the assembler version of your code. The assembler code is the direct mnemonic representation of the opcodes ("machine language").

[With `gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) (consider adding `-masm=intel` if you prefer the Intel over the default AT&T syntax):

```
gcc -S ...
```

to my knowledge other compilers on unixoid systems also support `-S`. This will skip compilation and you'll want to look for files named after your source files, but with the extension replaced by `.s`.

Or [with MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx):

```
cl.exe /FA
```

... you may add `c` (i.e. `/FAc`) which will also compile it. You'll want to look for `.asm` files then.

Also see: [How can I see the assembly code for a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840321)

After this is done, you basically compare (relevant!) source lines. What's relevant depends on your own (or your teacher's) judgement, however. There are tools out there to count [SLOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code), e.g. the one referenced in this Wikipedia article: [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/).

NB: the statement in the first paragraph about direct representation is slightly incorrect. If we're talking macro assembler then this doesn't hold, because of the macros. But even though MSVC uses a macro assembler as backend, the compiler doesn't make much use of the macro capabilities, so they shouldn't interfere (*much*) in the SLOC-counting.