# gcc assembly output

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

I'm wanting to look at the assembly output from a particular piece of code and generally I prefer reading nasm syntax compared to AT&T syntax. Is there a convenient way to get nasm assembly format output from gcc?

Comment: See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc/137056#137056

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want `intel` syntax. I believe it's achieved with

```
-masm=intel
```

**EDIT**

Of course, you can also use `objdump` for this:

```
objdump -M intel -d <binary>
```