# How to view the machine language of a compiled c++ file?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I wrote a simple c++ program that prints "Hello World!"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
cout<<"Hello World!\n";
}
```

I then compiled it using g++

```
$ g++ Desktop/sample.cpp -o Desktop/hello
```

How would I be able to view the machine language, is it just

```
$ less Desktop/hello
```

?

I'm just curious to see what "machine language" looks like.  Here's a sample from the above command

```
C>^D<A1><F4><9E>^D^H<83><F8><FF>t^S<BB><F4><9E>^D^Hf<90><83><EB>^D<FF>Ћ^C<83><F8><FF>u<F4><83><C4>^D[]Ð<90>U
<89><E5>S<83><EC>^D<E8>^@^@^@^@[<81>Ì^X^@^@<E8><<FE><FF><FF>Y[<C9><C3>^C^@^@^@^A^@^B^@Hello World!
^@^@^@^AESC^C; ^@^@^@^C^@^@^@<A4><FE><FF><FF>@^@^@^@<C8><FE><FF><FF>\^@^@^@^H<FF><FF><FF>x^@^
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc

Comment: You want a [Hex Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor)

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought machine language is NOT assembly language.  Machine language is a lower level language that's read by the hardware.  http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/M/machine_language.html.  Is machine language assembly language?

Comment: @Led: No, it's not.  I don't know why everyone is talking about assembly language.

Comment: You could regard the assembly as being the human-readable form of what you are looking at with less.

Comment: Benjamin LOL!!! Yeah but I appreciate the context of brining assembly in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you compile with the `-S` option, it will spit out the assembler output and stop.  Make sure you use the `-o` option to set the output file to `sample.s`:

```
g++ -S -o sample.s sample.cpp
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to compile it this way:

```
  g++ -g -c -Wa,-alh Desktop/sample.cpp -o Desktop/hello
```

The look at the assembler code with:

```
 objdump -d Desktop/hello
```

Comment: `$ g++ -v` `gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)` I'm using 32bit ubuntu

Comment: I tried it also on ubuntu with  g++ 4.6.1 and it worked. I do not have g++ 4.4 available, so I cannot try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Use `xxd` on the binary generated by `g++` to view the machine code. Assembly is an abstract version of machine code and is not neccessarily what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xxd -g 1 hello | more` to view the binary content of the executable file 'hello' or any binary file you want to check.