# Generate assembly for a target

Tags: cmake

I am trying to pass `-S` to GCC for one of my executables. I tried this:

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-S")
```

but I get "file format not recognized; treating as linker script"

(It builds fine without that line)

Is there something wrong with passing `-S` like this? Or is there another way to have CMake output the assembly .s files?

Comment: I learned that if you type 'make help' on a CMake project, you will see a list of targets. "MyTarget.s" is one of them, so simply doing "make MyTarget.s" produces the assembly I was looking for.

Comment: I believe that `make MyTarget.s` did what you wanted because your target has a source file named `MyTarget.c` or `MyTarget.f90` and that in general `make <target-name>.s` would not work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're trying to actually build `MyTarget` *and* leave the generated assembly, you can replace `-S` with `-save-temps` and then do `make MyTarget`

Comment: found it interesting that having both -S and -save-temps specified did not leave the .s files, but only -save-temps specified did

Answer (score 30):

CMake has targets built in for both assembler and preprocessor output. For a file called `src.cpp`, CMake generates the target `src.s` for assembler output and `src.i` for the preprocessor output. It generates the assembler/preprocessor outputs for each target seperately in case the compile flags are different. Using the make generator for your CMake project, you can get the assembler and preprocessor outputs like this:

```
make src.s   # assembler output
make src.i   # preprocessor output
```

Comment: How can I combine this with interlaced source comments, e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/137479/388010)? À la `g++ -g -O0 -c -fverbose-asm -Wa,-adhln test.cpp > test.lst`

Comment: For now, I manually alter the right makefile and adding `-fverbose-asm` after it has been generated. Then I can use the `as -alhnd` bit.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to @ingomueller.net's answer.  CMake does have `.s` targets but for multi directory projects, you have to navigate to the right directory within your build directory to get it.  That directory is determined by the location of the `CMakeLists.txt` file that creates the target and the `add_subdirectory()` commands that get to it.

If

```
<source_dir>/<d1>/CMakeLists.txt
```

has

```
add_excutable(x <d2>/file.c)
#or
add_library(x <d2>/file.c)
```

Then you can run `make <d2>/file.s` if you go to the right directory first.
In general, this will be the value of `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` where the target is created.  In most cases this would be

```
<build_dir>/<d1>
```

But this can be different because `add_subdirectory()` can take two arguments which can change things.  For example, say `<d1>` is `a/b`, if the toplevel CMakeLists.txt does `add_subdirectory(a/b/ c)`, then you will need to go to `<build_dir>/c`.  Also the second argument of add_subdirectory can be an absolute path.  And since we can get to the `CMakeLists.txt` file that creates the target through multiple `add_subdirectory()` commands, the only general answer is "whatever the value of `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` is where the target is created".

CMake will print the path to the generated file which will be `CMakeFiles/<target_name>.dir/<d2>/file.c.s` relative to `$PWD`.

Also, note that you can do either `make <d2>/file.s` or `make <d2>/file.c.s` and both will generate the file `file.c.s` however you could have `file.c` and `file.f90` in the same directory, in that case `make <d2>/file.s` will generate two files `file.c.s` and `file.f90.s` but doing `make <d2>/file.c.s` will generate just one.

Answer (score 0):

When I figured out how to have CMake generate .s files, I wrote additional commands in CMakeLists.txt. This way you have more control over the assembly output, but the output won't be exactly same as the output of -save-temps.

```
# XXX You can use this block to check the assembly code
set( C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} )
if( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
  string( APPEND C_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}" )
elseif( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES RelWithDebInfo)
  string( APPEND C_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" )
endif()
string(REGEX REPLACE " " ";" C_FLAGS ${C_FLAGS})
get_target_property( SRCS target_exec SOURCES )
get_target_property( INCS target_exec INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
get_directory_property( DEFS COMPILE_DEFINITIONS )
foreach(SRC ${SRCS})
  string(APPEND SRC_FILES "../../${SRC};")
endforeach()
foreach(INC ${INCS})
  string(APPEND INC_DIR_OPTIONS "-I${INC};")
endforeach()
foreach(DEF ${DEFS})
  string(APPEND DEF_OPTIONS "-D${DEF};")
endforeach()
execute_process( COMMAND mkdir -p "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/asm_output"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} )
add_custom_target(gen_asm_files ALL
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} ${C_FLAGS} -S -fverbose-asm ${DEF_OPTIONS} ${INC_DIR_OPTIONS} ${SRC_FILES}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/asm_output"
  DEPENDS ${INCS} ${SRCS}
  COMMENT "Generating .s files for the executable 'target_exec'"
)
```

target_exec doesn't have to be an executable, it can be a library target.

You don't have to remove the .i preprocessed files and .bc bitcode files after the execution of the cmake commands since it exclusively generates .s files only.

I hope that I could help someone else by sharing it, for what it's worth.