Multistep compilation pipeline using Cmake
I have an embedded application project and I need to create a build process that takes a set of .c files and outputs a binary file at the end.
This question is focused on the following part of the build process:
I have a set of files, for example:
set(C_SOURCES
        ${Project_root}/SEGGER/SEGGER_RTT.c
        ${Project_root}/sdk/components/boards/boards.c
        ${Project_root}/sdk/modules/nrfx/mdk/system_nrf52840.c
        ${Project_root}/sdk/integration/nrfx/legacy/nrf_drv_clock.c
        ${Project_root}/sdk/integration/nrfx/legacy/nrf_drv_spi.c
        ${Project_root}/sdk/modules/nrfx/drivers/src/nrfx_clock.c
    ...
)

For each of these files, this should happen:
<myfile.c> -> <myfile.asm> -> <myfile.o>
where assembly from .c files to .asm files should happen by this command:
COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${INCLUDES} ${D_C_FLAGS} <file_name.c> -o ${Project_root}/Output/Debug/asm/<file_name.asm>

and the compilation from .asm to .o file should happen by this command:
COMMAND ${CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${INCL} ${D_ASM_FLAGS} <file_name.asm> -o ${Project_root}/Output/Debug/obj/<file_name.o>

How to achieve this in Cmake, ideally:

with the parallelism support of a generator such as Ninja
without having unique target specified for each file
with having include_directories() specified, and using Cmake magic to populate compiler include arguments for each file
support for target clean, that would get rid of the .asm and .o files
having one target that would trigger all the necessary operations
the source files should be recognized by the IDE (CLion) as part of the final target.

(I imagine the best practice would be to split the files into modules/components and include them as dependencies in the root target. But for the sake of simplicity, I don't care.)

Why do you ever need to split single step (compilation into object file) into multiple steps (compilation into asm file, and then into object file)? If you just want sometimes to debug by inspecting asm file, then CMake provides targets for generate such asm files by request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965019/generate-assembly-for-a-target

I wanted to skip that step altogether, but original IDE (Segger Embedded Studio) compiles that in two steps and it is to have more control over the assembly steps and compilation steps (by providing respective flags to assembler and compiler). So I want to reproduce it first and then start to throw things out and optimize the build process.
