# How to convert this c++ code to assembly ?

Tags: c++, assembly

How to convert this c++ code to assembly code ?

```
while(( A = getch()) != "0")
{
  switch(A){
    case "x":
     printf("x");
     break;
    case "w":
     printf("w");
    case "k":
     if(cx==0)
       continue;
     break;
     default: printf("error");
           }
}
```

specially how to convert: getch() != "0";

Comment: Duplicate? [How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc)

Comment: This is not the place where work is done for of you. Show us what you have tried, what didn't work, where you struggled, and ask specific questions.

Comment: `g++ -S -o assembly.s mycode.cpp` Done.

Comment: Whats the point of the C++ tag???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for x86 assembly, you can write

```
call   getchar
```

which will cause a trap. When the char is ready, it will be put in the `eax` register. You can then compare this value to the decimal value of char "0", which is 48.