# Rapidjson seg fault with g++ optimization

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, compiler-optimization, rapidjson

I am using Rapidjson and have noticed that when I turn on optimization in g++ (-O1/-O2/-O3) I am getting a segmentation fault. I think I have tracked it down to the GenericValue& AddMember() function within rapidjson.

```
GenericValue& AddMember(GenericValue& name, GenericValue& value, Allocator& allocator) {
    RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(IsObject());
    RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(name.IsString());

    Object& o = data_.o;
    if (o.size >= o.capacity) {
        if (o.capacity == 0) {
            o.capacity = kDefaultObjectCapacity;
            o.members = reinterpret_cast<Member*>(allocator.Malloc(o.capacity * sizeof(Member)));
        }
        else {
            SizeType oldCapacity = o.capacity;
            o.capacity += (oldCapacity + 1) / 2; // grow by factor 1.5
            o.members = reinterpret_cast<Member*>(allocator.Realloc(o.members, oldCapacity * sizeof(Member), o.capacity * sizeof(Member)));
        }
    }
    o.members[o.size].name.RawAssign(name);
    o.members[o.size].value.RawAssign(value);
    o.size++;
    return *this;
}
```

When debugging, I can see that kDefaultObjectCapacity ( is being optimized out (this is a static const SizeType kDefaultObjectCapacity = 16)

Therefore the line "o.capacity = kDefaultObjectCapacity;" is not being executed, and the malloc is mallocing 0 bytes then trying to cast it.

Why is this static const being removed?

I have tried making Object& o both volatile and static, neither worked.
Any ideas?

Thanks
Will

EDIT:
I can't easily run the tests as it's on an embedded platform, rapidjson is built using buildroot at the moment. I tried the unit tests but couldn't get them going on the target.

I can have a look at providing the assembly, but it's part of a big application so it might be difficult finding the right bit.

For info, this is the method that calls the rapidjson code and this is where the problem seems to be:

```
int16_t FrontEndJSONHandlers::get_run_cfg_packer(JSONEngine& json_engine, char *message, int32_t *length)
{
Document doc;

// Need to pack an empty request to get the data
doc.SetObject();
doc.AddMember(JSONRPC_MEMBER, JSONRPC_VERSION, doc.GetAllocator());
doc.AddMember(METHOD_MEMBER, JSON_RPC_METH_GET_RUN_CFG, doc.GetAllocator());
doc.AddMember(ID_MEMBER, json_engine.GetNextMessageID(), doc.GetAllocator());

// Format the message
json_engine.FormatMessageAndRegisterResponseHandler(&doc, &message, &length, get_run_cfg_handler);

return 0;
}
```

If I make Document doc static, it doesn't seg fault - not sure whether this is the best way around it though?

Comment: Can you show us the generated assembly, both with and without optimization? (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc)

Comment: Do the unit tests in the rapidjson bundle pass? It may be the application have corrupted memory somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty badly wrong, and in a way that makes me suspect you are also misunderstanding what you see in the debugger.  Try fixing the bugs first, before worrying about what the optimizer might be doing:

It appears that part of your intent is for o.capacity to end up `>` (or maybe you intended `>=`) o.size

But did you consider the case `o.size > kDefaultObjectCapacity` when o.capacity starts at zero?  More seriously, your comment about increasing by a factor of 1.5 is wrong for code that decreases capacity.  You probably intended `oldCapacity*3/2`

```
if (o.size >= o.capacity) {
    if (o.capacity == 0) {
        o.capacity = kDefaultObjectCapacity;
        o.members = reinterpret_cast<Member*>(allocator.Malloc(o.capacity * sizeof(Member)));
    }
    else {
        SizeType oldCapacity = o.capacity;
        o.capacity += (oldCapacity + 1) / 2; // grow by factor 1.5
        o.members = reinterpret_cast<Member*>(allocator.Realloc(o.members, oldCapacity * sizeof(Member), o.capacity * sizeof(Member)));
    }
}
```

Edit:  I was mistaken about a large part of the above.  But I still think a misunderstanding of what was seen in the debugger is a more likely explanation that the optimizer breaking that code.

Was the "90" mentioned decimal, or might it have been hex?  The optimizer certainly could skip multiplying by `sizeof(Member)` and go directly to the result of that multiplication.

Comment: `>=` is correct. When `size == capacity` it means the storage is just full and need to increase the capacity of storage. And also note that the line is `o.capacity += (oldCapacity + 1) / 2`, which adds `ceil(oldCapacity * 0.5)` to make the 1.5 increment factor.

Comment: Sorry, just edited post, I made a typo. o.capacity is originally 0 bytes, so it is going into "if (o.capacity == 0) {". Then it skips the line to set o.capacity to kDefaultObjectCapacity and o.capacity is still 0 when the Malloc is called.

Comment: Now that you removed the "90" that I read so much into, there may be no value left in my answer.  My alternate answer would be I still don't believe the optimizer went that badly wrong.  So we need to see a big enough chunk, preferably a whole module that could be compiled, but at least enough to include the definition of that constant you mentioned as well as the declaration of the data members of `Object`.  If this is all in code you downloaded, a link would be nice, since I don't know how to search it.

Comment: Yes sorry about the 90! Good point, I should have posted a link. It's here: https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/master/include/rapidjson/document.h The function that seems to be acting strange is AddMember, line 993

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue, compiling with GCC 4.9: I get a segmentation fault when an optimization flag is specified (-On).  It's very easy to duplicate, here's the code:

```
//...
#include "extern/rapidjson/document.h"
//...
void* MyThread(void*)
{
   std::cout << "Start of MyThread" << std::endl;

   rapidjson::Document doc;
   doc.Parse("{ \"NAME\": \"Peter\", \"AGE\": 38, \"Male\": true}");

   std::cout << "End!";

   return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   pthread_t thread;

   pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &MyThread, NULL);

   std::string str;
   std::cout << "Press <Return>"  << std::endl;
   std::getline(std::cin, str);

   return 0;
 }
```

The key here is the document being created and parsed in a separate thread.  If we call "MyThread(NULL)" directly in the main(), we won't get any bug.

A similar code with Visual Studio 2012, optimized, runs fine.  I ran a VS code analysis and no error was found.  The only difference is the threading:

```
std::thread th([] { MyThread(NULL); }); 
th.join();
```

===============================================

**The issue has been fixed after version 1.0.2.  Using the latest code works fine.**

Comment: I'd suggest posting this as a new question ("why does the thread version crash?") . You can put a comment on this question linking to your new question if you want. So far there is no evidence that this is actually the answer to OP's question.

Comment: although I would suggest calling `pthread_join` before `return 0;` at least ... if you fall off the end of main then it may destroy any static objects that `rapidjson` used , and then your thread tries to use those objects and gets into trouble

Comment: another thing is that `cout` may not have been thread safe prior to C++11

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Using the last code from the repo fixed the issue.  I did try before posting the question, but I had a setup problem that caused the old version (1.0.2) to be used...