# How to interpret disassembed C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

Let's say I run `objdump -d` on an object file generated by a *C* compiler and I get this disassembly:

```
0000000000400b5e <main>:
 400b5e: 55 push %rbp
 400b5f: 48 89 e5 mov %rsp,%rbp
 400b62: bf 50 0a 49 00 mov $0x490a50,%edi
 400b67: e8 04 0b 00 00 callq 401670 <_IO_puts>
 400b6c: 5d pop %rbp
 400b6d: c3 retq 
 400b6e: 66 90 xchg %ax,%ax
```

I'm not sure how to interpret everything here. Take the line:

```
400b62: bf 50 0a 49 00 mov $0x490a50,%edi
```

I get what the `mov` statement is doing, but what does the `400b62` mean? What does the `bf 50 0a 49 00` mean? I couldn't find anything on the Internet explaining how to read this stuff.

Comment: `bf 50 0a 49 00` is the machine code for `mov $0x490a50,%edi`. Usually, the mnemonics are all aligned to a common column so this is easy to see.

Comment: You're better off using the [compiler option that creates an assembly file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc). It will annotate the assembly code with the corresponding C statements, variables, and literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `400b62` is the address of the instruction. The `bf 50 0a 49 00` are the bytes that make up the instruction. In this case, the instruction at `400b62` it sets the register `%edi` to 0x490a50. Here `bf` means "set edi" and `50 0a 49 00` are the bytes for 0x490a50 in little endian order (as Intel processors do).

If you want to be able to read each of the instructions, it takes a bit of decoding but can be done. The best reference in my experience is the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), but they are not for the faint of heart.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but what does it mean "the bytes that make up the instruction"?

Comment: @KingHenryV, see my expanded answer.

Comment: @KingHenryV the CPU doesn't execute the text source code, it understands only instruction opcodes, the x86 CPU understands `bf` as `mov edi,imm32` instruction, so it will read also next four bytes to fetch the `imm32` data. Each CPU from different vendor has different instructions and opcodes, that's why x86 Assembly is different from ARM Assembly. To execute your source code, you must first compile it with assembler into those instruction opcodes (machine code), then the CPU can execute your program.

Answer (score 2):

Start with an assembly language primer, such as https://speakerdeck.com/vsergeev/x86-assembly-primer-for-c-programmers which is good if you already know C.

In your code, what matters is

```
mov $0x490a50,%edi
callq 401670 <_IO_puts>
```

First 6 arguments on x86-64 are passed through registers
`rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx r8, r9`. (`edi` is half of `rdi`), so this passes one argument to a to-be called function and then calls the function.

The decoded name (`_IO_puts`) suggests you're dealing with an implementation of `puts`, which implies `0x490a50` is the hexadecimal representation of the memory address of a string that was passed to it.

The original main will likely be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { puts("hello world"); }
```

Comment: `0x490a50` is memory address (`const char*`), under "hexadecimal representation of a string" I would imagine rather eight `char` values stored directly in the `rdi`, not in memory, which is not the case for `puts`.

Comment: @Ped7g My head automatically decays strings to pointers. C has spoiled me. Anyway, I have fixed the text of the answer now.