# Location of register variable

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

When you declare a variable with `register` attribute in C, how can you find out which CPU register it is stored in?

```
register int i;
```

Comment: you don't because the register keyword doesn't guarantee it will even be in a register, it is just a hint to the compiler.

Comment: How would you do it in case it really goes into a register?

Comment: You can read the assembly that the compiler outputs.

Comment: Read the asm the compiler emitted to see what it did.  `gcc -O3 -S -fverbose-asm` can be useful; it adds comments on each line naming the operands.  If `i` wasn't optimized away, or the uses of it transformed into something else, then it may show up in the comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output, and also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc

Comment: Even if you don't use `register` the variable could still be stored in a register. Generally it is best to leave this to the compiler, which will probably decide this itself anyway (even if you add `register` to some variables).

Comment: @Tuhnri Note that with modern SSA-based compilers, there isn't really a single register the variable is hold in.  Rather, the compile translates each variable into many single-use variables and assigns a register to each of them.  It's not uncommon to see a variable change registers all the time in assembly.