# std::cout vs printf; any differences in machine language?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, optimization

Out of these two:

```
printf("abc\n");
```

and

```
std::cout << "abc\n";
```

I know the correct way to code is to use the cout line.
But does the program differ from an assembly/machine code perspective? (like, one is faster, or smaller in size?) 
Or do both give an identical program output?

Comment: Give it a try: [How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc)

Comment: The second one probably generates a lot more assembly code.

Comment: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ULguJf) is a great tool for checking things like that.

Comment: People rating the question, don't really read it. 
The other topic doesn't show anything of 'machine language//assembly code'.