# How do I generate an assembly listing in a VSCode build using gcc?

Tags: assembly, gcc, visual-studio-code, build

I'm trying to build a c/c++ file and generate an assembly listing file at the same time. I can't get it to work. I can build it on the command line and generate the file but I can't do it from within the VSCode build.
My tasks.json file is as follows:

```
"tasks": [
       {

            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-S",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "My Build Task"
        },
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: What is the output? Did you get any error message?

Comment: `cppbuild` is an invalid value for `type`, it pops up regularly, what is the source of this?

Comment: I don't get any errors on the output. The .c file builds to an .exe file and I can step through and debug it with no issues.

Comment: The source for this is a simple hello world .c file.

Comment: A command like `gcc -S foo.c -o foo.exe` will generate an assembly source file but write it to a file named `foo.exe` (which will of course not actually execute).  If you're able to run the file then I suspect what you're running is not what gcc created.

Comment: [How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137038) mentions both `-S` and `-save-temps` (which can save asm while still creating a `.o` or `.exe`)

Comment: the -save-temps works on the command line but not through the tasks file.