# Is there a way to see Machine code and C++ code side by side like how you can with NASM?

Tags: c++, x86, hex, nasm, machine-code

Is there some sort of program that allows you to see Machine code and C++ code side by side like how Netwide Assembler does it?

For example

```
machine code here #include <iostream>
                  
machine code here int main() {
machine code here    cout << "Hello, World!";
                  }
```

and how NASM does it

```
     1                                  section .text
     2                                      global _start
     3                                      
     4                                  _start:
     5 00000000 66B804000000                mov eax,4
     6 00000006 66BB01000000                mov ebx,1
     7 0000000C 66B9[00000000]              mov ecx,message
     8 00000012 66BA0D000000                mov edx,len
     9                                      
    10 00000018 CD80                        int 0x80
    11                                      
    12 0000001A 66B801000000                mov eax,1
    13                                      
    14 00000020 CD80                        int 0x80
    15                                      
    16                                  section .data
    17 00000000 48656C6C6F2C20576F-         message db "Hello, World!"
    17 00000009 726C6421           
    18                                      len equ $-message
```

Comment: Check out https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @BrechtSanders While that is interesting, that is not what I am exactly looking for. Sorry, for not being clear, what I'm looking for is something that converts the C++ code to something like the hex next to the x86 assembly code.

Comment: @LuaCoder You can turn on hex if you want: https://godbolt.org/z/WfYrGK3Ms

Comment: `objdump -dS` interleaves source lines and normal objdump disassembly, as in the top answer on [How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137038).  If you want hex machine code, not just asm source for some reason, that's probably a good way to go.  I find the Godbolt "binary mode" output looks messy and hard to read.

Comment: You need a disassembler to inspect the generated code. In the past I have used hiew (hacker's view) for this but don't know if this is still an active project