compiler optimization issue / variable has wrong value
I define variables as
volatile sig_atomic_t v1;
volatile int v2;

Then in one process (thread) perform
v1 = false;
v2 = 0;
...
v2 = (some_var);
v1 = true;

and in another process (thread)
while(!v1) { (doing some tasks not related to v1 and v2); }
if(v2 == 0) { (do something); }

The problem I get is v2 sometimes set to 0 when while ends. while is proven to finish when v1 becomes true. (some_var) is proven to be non-zero. Using gcc.
What do I miss here?

If you look at the generated code, has it optimized away the while loop?

Does this happen even if you disable optimization?

@Barmar I do not know where to look at (where's the generated code - assembly?) How to disable optimizations? I also amended that while is not empty, there's something inside. I suspect there's something I am doing wrongly causing such effects, not sure if it is a compiler issue.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc for how to save the assembly output.

it's possible that v1 = 0; happens in the other thread between the end of the while loop and the if statement.

volatile for thread synchronization is wrong. You need _Atomic (for C) or std::atomic (for C++) instead. Please tag the language that you are asking about. volatile neither guarantees atomicity nor any memory ordering except with respect to other volatile access in the same thread. This is also true for sig_atomic_t which only has special properties with regards to signal handlers on the same thread, not between multiple threads.

@user17732522 I thought app wide volatile means read/write memory location every time it is needed for whoever aware about this modifier, and sig_atomic_t means perform operations in single cycle (or any other atomic way) to eliminate race conditions. Therefore if I update some flag after I update other variables will make other thread catch up those variables after it sees updated flag.

@Anonymous "read/write memory location every time it is needed for whoever aware about this modifier,": I don't exactly follow what you mean. volatile only means that the compiler shall strictly perform the load or store to memory as it would happen on the abstract machine and that all of these loads and stores shall happen in the same order as on the abstract machine. That doesn't imply anything about aotmicity or memory ordering with regards to other loads/stores. The compiler and CPU are free to reorder them however they want.

@Anonymous volatile sig_atomic_t does not mean that the operation must be performed in a single cycle. It only guarantees atomicity with respect to signal handlers on the same thread and that its value seen by the signal handler will be specified and consistent with respect to the state of the invoking thread. It doesn't guarantee anything about other threads.

That, in order to achieve these guarantees, loads and stores of volatile sig_atomic_t must happen as single instructions (which is not the same as cycles either) is an implementation detail of the compiler.

@Anonymous Read this re: volatile: Volatile: Almost Useless for Multi-Threaded Programming and this: Should volatile Acquire Atomicity and Thread Visibility Semantics?  N.B. the implication that volatile therefore lacks any atomicity and thread visibility semantics...

What CPU architecture?  On weakly ordered architectures (e.g. ARM), even if the load and store instructions are executed in the proper order, the CPU is still allowed to reorder them, such that another thread may see them in a different order.  Avoiding this requires memory barrier instructions, which volatile will not insert.  As Andrew says, the intended solution for this is _Atomic.

Unfortunately, your code and comments about volatile suggest that you are working under a lot of misconceptions about the C memory model for multithreading (post-C11).  You may have to do a lot of unlearning and relearning before you go back to writing any code.

@NateEldredge I did not invent this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming) but further in the text it says C voltaile is not that described in the header. This IMHO is just broken.

Did you see the paragraph that begins "Operations on volatile variables are not atomic, nor do they establish a proper happens-before relationship for threading."?  In fact, the article says over and over again that volatile is not adequate for variables shared between threads.

volatile has nothing to do with atomic access.
Preventing the compiler from doing strange optimizations when it doesn't realize that a callback is called from the OS not a program will only get you so far - in fact PC-like compilers like gcc are smart enough to know that callbacks may be called, so volatile on variables shared between threads probably doesn't add anything meaningful to the average gcc Linux application. (It would in case your target is some more or less dysfunctional embedded systems compiler though.)
However, there is still the core issue of re-entrancy and protection against race condition bugs. Check out for example Using volatile in embedded C development - that's about interrupt service routines but they behave just like threads when it comes to re-entrancy. Swap "ISR" for thread in my answer there, and emphasis on the last sentence:

When writing C, all communication between an ISR and the background program must be protected against race conditions. Always, every time, no exceptions. The size of the MCU data bus does not matter, because even if you do a single 8 bit copy in C, the language cannot guarantee atomicity of operations. Not unless you use the C11 feature _Atomic. If this feature isn't available, you must use some manner of semaphore or disable the interrupt during read etc. Inline assembler is another option. volatile does not guarantee atomicity.
What can happen is this:

Load value from stack into register
Interrupt occurs
Use value from register

And then it doesn't matter if the "use value" part is a single instruction in itself. Sadly, a significant portion of all embedded systems programmers are oblivious to this, probably making it the most common embedded systems bug ever. Always intermittent, hard to provoke, hard to find.

Feels like I've written hundreds of answers about this. Here's another:

What volatile does:

Guarantees an up-to-date value in the variable, if the variable is modified from an external source (a hardware register, an interrupt, a
different thread, a callback function etc).
Blocks all optimizations of read/write access to the variable.
Prevent dangerous optimization bugs that can happen to variables shared between several threads/interrupts/callback functions, when the
compiler does not realize that the thread/interrupt/callback is called
by the program. (This is particularly common among various
questionable embedded system compilers, and when you get this bug it
is very hard to track down.)

What volatile does not:

It does not guarantee atomic access or any form of thread-safety.
It cannot be used instead of a mutex/semaphore/guard/critical section. It cannot be used for thread synchronization.

What volatile may or may not do:

It may or may not be implemented by the compiler to provide a memory barrier, to protect against instruction cache/instruction
pipe/instruction re-ordering issues in a multi-core environment. You
should never assume that volatile does this for you, unless the
compiler documentation explicitly states that it does.


Regarding the memory barrier part and different possible ways to read/misinterpret the C standard:
Why does memory-barrier prohibit optimization on static global variable?

Thank you very much! What's about volatile atomic_int? It seems not cause warnings and works (so far) without symptoms I described in the question.

@Anonymous atomic_int and _Atomic int is the same thing if that's what you're asking. It's valid standard C as per C11 or later.

@Anonymous You don't need the volatile if you are only concerned with thread synchronization (compiler bugs mentioned in this answer aside). It won't do anything useful for that. As this answer says, you need the volatile if the memory location might be modified externally and/or the exact sequence of loads/stores to memory is relevant external to the program. What you need to take care of however is to use sufficiently strong memory ordering when accessing the atomic_int, i.e. in your use case at least acquire on the load an release on the store.

@Anonymous And only on v1 btw. v2 doesn't need to be either volatile or atomic (at least based only on the use that you presented).

@user17732522 that was supposedly the problem of v2 being written later than v1, that's why second code may had been reading 0 from the v2 at time it needs this v2. Therefore both must be as strong as possible to prevent execution reordering and late writing/updating.

@Anonymous No, that's not true. Memory ordering on the load/store of v1 is all you need. It implies that the store to v2 which is sequenced before the store of v1 in the first thread will happen-before the load of v2 in the second thread if the load of v1 obtains its value from the previously mentioned store in the first thread, because v2 is sequenced-after the load of v1 in the second thread. That is, assuming the load and store of v1 have acquire/release memory ordering. See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order.

@Anonymous And if you use only relaxed ordering instead, then having both be atomic doesn't save you from reordering either. The memory ordering choice is the major problem you need to get right to avoid the bug in your program. And as mentioned in a comment under the question, it seems that you are not thinking correctly in terms of the C memory model what memory ordering means. It is not (intrinsically) about compiler optimizations. Compilers happening to be able to optimize with knowledge of the memory model is just a side effect from abstracting actual hardware memory models.

@Anonymous Of course if the first thread continues to write to v2 even after its store of true to v1, then you need to think about synchronization of this store with your load as well. And then you would again have a data race, which _Atomic on v2 would prevent.

@user17732522 I think I got it but the only viable solution (not workaround) I see is to change platform to FPGA-based processor I developed which will be free of such issues on purpose. With ARM there's no control over what processor wants to do. Thus I must accept the risk of this anyway.

@Anonymous The viable solution is to simply use _Atomic correctly according to specification. That will work perfectly fine on ARM as well. It only gets tricky if you do not have a compiler or platform that can support _Atomic.

No, the point was to load data into structure and then set a flag. This did not work, intermittently. On slower systems failure rate was lower, on faster it was almost instant. I need a way to stop this nightmare and ensure first thread does what I request it to do in order I told it to do, and second to get results when it notices flag (v1 in my example) set. In this model there's no problem if second thread will read flag as false once (due to metastability), next time it will read it right.

@Anonymous Well, yes, because you never told it in what order to do it. There is no obvious mapping of source code order of statements/expressions to the hardware's memory view. You tell the compiler and CPU the order you need by making v1 e.g. an atomic_bool, replacing v1 = true; by atomic_store_explicit(&v1, true, memory_order_release); and while(!v1) by while(!atomic_load_explicit(&v1, memory_order_acquire)) and then your program will have the semantics you want and it will work the way you want it. (Other races in code you haven't shown notwithstanding.)
