Is there any way to explicitly tell compiler to stop optimization
Linux, C, GCC, ARM (Allwinner H3). Is it possible to get the following equivalent functionality (pseudocode):
#pragma optimizations-stop
#pragma registers-flush

a=10;
while(*b != 0) c++;
if(a == 0) { do something; }

#pragma optimizations-start

with result of location of a being explicitly written with value 10, then every loop cycle value of b is read from the memory and then read value from location b is compared to 0, and then if not zero c is rmw'ed with +1, and when loop breaks location of a is being explicitly read from the memory and compared to 0?
And, what's important, instructions are executed in the specific order programmer laid them out in the program, not as compiler or CPU thinks the best.
Please withhold with discussion of what is impossible, let's discuss how to achieve the required result.
If it is not possible at the C/GCC level, I will be glad for suggestions to implement that as inline assembly.

It’s pretty straightforward by declaring a, b and c as volatile. Is that what you’re after?

Of course not. See the question I asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78722496/compiler-optimization-issue-variable-has-wrong-value. In addition I learnt that CPU itself (especially ARM) is going to decide for me how to execute MY program.

Hmm. As the comments there point out, volatile does not perform synchronisation, which is necessary for multithreading. Nevertheless, volatile does ensure that every variable is read and written to as specified in your program. The reason concurrent access isn’t well-defined is due to where these variables are stored on multiprocessor architectures (simplified).

Anyway: if your question is “how do I disable the CPU cache and prevent instruction prefetching, etc.?” then I think the answer is: you can’t. (Though I might be wrong)

There's 3 different issues one has to keep separated: 1) prevent compiler optimizations, 2) prevent race condition bugs and 3) prevent instruction re-ordering. volatile definitely does 1), it definitely does not do 2) and it may or may not do 3) depending on how literal one reads the C standard. The most sensible way to read the standard is that the implementation (compiler + system) is not allowed to perform re-ordering across a volatile access = memory barrier. However, some chose to read the standard as volatile access might not be re-ordered in relation to another side effect.

I posted an answer below your other question addressing these 3 separate issues.

GCC has #pragma GCC optimize(…) which answers the headline question.  I've not needed to use the "big hammer" (is that Mjölnir?) so I'm not sure whether that is better, worse, or just different from the pragma.  IME, the pragma is typically used around dubious code that the compiler mishandles — often a full function, sometimes several functions, occasionally part of a function.

"In addition I learnt that CPU itself (especially ARM) is going to decide for me how to execute MY program." Yep, that's how modern CPUs work, and a large part of why they work as fast as they do.  If you're so fundamentally opposed to the concept, then your best bet is probably a time machine to travel back to the year 1982.

The "big hammer" is a GCC extension, asm __volatile__("": : :"memory"). This is the full memory barrier used by the Linux kernel.
Note that this does not do what you ask for in the title. It doesn't stop optimizations at all. It does however achieve the ordering that you describe.
Also note that c++ is a read-modify-write. It's not atomic, and there are no memory barriers between the parts. The compiler can reasonably keep c in a register, and do a read-modify-write on the register. You'd need something like volatile int* pc = &c; to avoid that.
Finally, to take your other post into account, the memory barrier on one thread won't magically make another thread cooperate. You'd need barriers on both threads. And that's why they're rare - you can usually use proper synchronization instead.

Could atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst); (#include <stdatomic.h>) be used as the memory barrier?

"you'd need something like volatile int* pc = &c; to avoid that.": Even if the access is via volatile I do not think that there is any guarantee that an increment will be performed in one combined load/store. If I remember correctly, there was even implementation divergence on that between GCC and Clang.

@user17732522: Correct. You only prevent the "store in register while incrementing" part. It's definitely not atomic, nor does it synchronize with other threads.

asm __volatile__("": : :"memory") seems to be only a compile-time reordering barrier. It doesn't add any instructions for memory synchronization (https://godbolt.org/z/3z6o3h9xb). So I am not sure whether this is enough to solve OP's problems. On x86 it will behave like acquire/release, but not sequential consistency. That's enough for OP, but e.g. on ARM I do not think it results in sufficient memory ordering guarantees.

Using _Atomic for all the variables in question will achieve this:

Every read and write to an _Atomic variable will correspond to an actual load or store instruction being executed.  (While this is not a formal guarantee of the C standard, in practice compilers do not try to optimize them out.)

Those loads and stores will not be reordered by the compiler.

Memory barrier instructions will be inserted where needed, to prevent any reordering by the CPU and ensure that they are observed in the same order by every other thread / CPU which also uses proper barriers.  (The default memory ordering for atomic is sequential consistency.  To avoid any of these memory barriers, you'd need to use functions like atomic_load_explicit).

The c++ will be performed with an atomic read-modify-write instruction or sequence of instructions (e.g. ARM LDREX/STREX), so that no writes to c can be performed by any other thread in between the read and write.

Accesses to non-_Atomic variables will not be reordered after a store, nor before a load.  (You can't prevent reorderings in the other directions, except by making the other variables _Atomic as well.)


Note that using volatile, as suggested elsewhere, achieves 1 and 2, but typically not 3, 4, 5.  Moreover, any unsynchronized concurrent access by multiple threads to a variable which is not _Atomic, even if it is volatile, causes undefined behavior for the entire program according to the C standard (a data race).

Compilers never move instructions across memory barriers. E.g.:
inst1
inst2
memory_barrier
inst3
inst4

The compiler may swap inst1 and inst2 or inst3 and inst4 but nothing about the memory barrier will move below it or the other way round. If you force a memory barrier after every instruction, nothing will ever change in order.
Nor do they assume that values are the same across memory barriers. E.g.
if (a == fetch->some->value) ...
if (b == fetch->some->value) ...

may be compiled as
tmp = fetch->some->value
if (a == tmp) ...
if (b == tmp) ...

but not if the code is
if (a == fetch->some->value) ...
memory_barrier
if (b == fetch->some->value) ...

Also keep in mind that even if your compiler does not re-order instructions, the CPU still may during execution (x86 does that all the time and very aggressively). No compiler option will prevent that this from happening, it will even happen with totally unoptimized code. But CPUs follow the same rules as compilers, they don't move instructions across memory barriers.
You've been using memory barriers for years without even realizing it. For example, every mutex lock or unlock is a memory barrier, because whenever you enter a locked region, the compiler must not make any assumptions about the values you are accessing there (which may have been changed by another thread that previously held the lock), and of course the compiler must not move instructions into or out of a locked region for obvious reasons.
Prior to C11, there was no cross-platform way to place a memory barrier in your code that would work across compilers. Of course, operating systems and compilers would provide proprietary ways to do this, because otherwise you couldn't implement certain threading features for the platform.
E.g. macOS offered a function named OSMemoryBarrier() in libkern/OSAtomic.h, a function that does nothing other than telling the compiler that there is a memory barrier and whose implementation contains a CPU instruction that CPUs also consider to be a memory barrier.
But with C11, there's now a standard way: atomic_thread_fence(). This is a full memory barrier if the argument is memory_order_seq_cst. If you use any other argument, it may not be a full barrier on some CPUs that's because a full barrier is not required under all circumstances and some CPUs have instructions that represent different kind of barriers, which are usually faster than a full barrier but provide less guarantees. Yet if you want to stop all re-ordering and ensure that memory is re-read on every access, you need a full barrier.
Note that a memory barrier does not make your code atomic, nor does it provide thread safety. It's not a lock, and operations before and after it are no more or less atomic than they would be without it. All a memory barrier does is tell the compiler and the CPU three things:

Don't move code from above below this barrier.

Don't move code from below above this barrier.

Memory values can be different above and below this barrier, even though there's no visible code that changes them.


